# Using the Command-line Command to launch Sublime Text 2 on OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, sublimetext2

I just started reading Michael Hartl's book on Rails and I've run across a problem in the setup phase. Hartl keeps referring to making a file in my home directory, but I'm not quite sure how to do this. For example, when I try to setup the command line for sublime text the instructions tell me to do this: Assuming you've placed Sublime Text 2 in the Applications folder, and that you have a ~/bin directory in your path, you can run:

ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl

My problem is that I don't know how to put a ~/bin directory in my path. I know this is real basic but any help would be greatly appreciation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create or edit `~/.profile` (works with both bash and zsh)

add the following

`export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin`

The line above is saying, overwrite the `PATH` environment variable and set it to the previous path plus `~/bin`

Now when you try to run a command, bash will look in all the colon separated paths in your `PATH` environment variable for an executable.

To see your entire `PATH`, type `echo $PATH` in a terminal. Or better yet, type `env` to see all environment variables.

Comment: That's the right way to add `~/bin` to your path, but you'll need to create the directory as well. To do that, type `mkdir ~/bin` in the Terminal.

Comment: Correct. This assumes `~/bin` exists. Thanks Emily.

Comment: [see this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)

Comment: @Kyle thanks, it's a mess. Each shell is different and I'm using zsh so I think it uses .zshrc always, independent if there is a login or not

Answer (score 1):

### On your terminal

> $ mkdir ~/bin
> $ sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl

### Edit ~/.base_profile

> export PATH=$PATH:~/bin

### usage:

open current directory:

> subl .

Answer (score 0):

In your `~/.bashrc` file add to the end:

```
 PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```