# Undoing termial command to open files in Sublime

Tags: terminal, sublimetext2

I recently did a tutorial that shows how to run a script to open all files in a folder in Sublime text 2 by navigating to the fodler and typing Subl .

It now opens blank windows when running the script, and so I want to revert, but am unsure how. The command I used is

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /bin/subl
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `ln -s`... creates a symbolic link to the Sublime Text 2.app in the bin directory.  (A symbolic link is similar to an Alias in the Finder.)   You can remove the symbolic link by opening the (hidden) /bin folder in the finder, and moving the "subl" file to the trash.

Assuming you are on OSX, you can open the /bin folder by typing `open /bin` in the terminal (You can also open the hidden /bin folder in the finder using the Go To Folder command in the Finder's "go menu.)

You may be asked for an adminstation password to drag the subl file (symbolic link) to the trash.

There are other answers on stackoverflow for getting the command to work, like: 
[Using the Command-line Command to launch Sublime Text 2 on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887083/using-the-command-line-command-to-launch-sublime-text-2-on-os-x?rq=1)