# Command not found after npm install in zsh

Tags: macos, zsh, npm, vows

I'm having some problems installing [vows](http://vowsjs.org) via npm in zsh. Here's what I get. I tried installing it with and without the -g option. Do you have any idea what's wrong here?

```
[❤  ~/Desktop/sauce-node-demo:master] npm install -g vows
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vows
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/vows
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eyes
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/diff
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/eyes
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/diff
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/vows -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/vows/bin/vows
vows@0.6.4 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/vows
├── eyes@0.1.8
└── diff@1.0.3
[❤  ~/Desktop/sauce-node-demo:master] vows
zsh: command not found: vows
```

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the shell's path cache via rehash ?

Comment: still nothing after doing this =/

Comment: I don't know why, but going to bash (by typing bash itself and hit enter) in the same terminal then switching back to zsh (by typing zsh itself and hit enter), fixes it!!

Answer (score 125, accepted):

If you installed Node.js using Homebrew, npm binaries can be found in `/usr/local/share/npm/bin`.

You should make sure this directory is in your PATH environment variable. So, in your `~/.zshrc` file add

```
export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: On mac, I added `export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"` to my `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: $HOME/.npm-global/bin worked for me with npm v6.9.0

Comment: What if you didn't install Node.js via Homebrew or you can't remember? And how do you find 'usr/local/share/npm/bin'?

Answer (score 210):

add `source /home/YOUUSERNAME/.bash_profile` at the beginning of `~/.zshrc`

And all missing commands will be detected.

For **Mac** users : add `source /Users/YOUUSERNAME/.bash_profile`

Comment: For me I had to source ~/.bashrc

Comment: I'm using WSL on Windows 10, and I had to add `source /home/USERNAME/.profile' to get it to work, but it worked like a charm

Comment: I had to source .bashrc instead of bash_profile.  When I sourced bash_profile I got a ton of commands not found in zsh

Comment: My user folder in Mac OS Catalina does not contain this `.bash_profile`. I cant find it with search either. After updating the `.zshrc` file and reopening the terminal, its first line was `no such file or directory: /Users/m...i/.bash_profile`. Might this be a breaking change of Catalina?

Comment: This also works for Mac users: `source /Users/$USER/.bash_profile` or maybe even easier `source $HOME/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 72):

If you have added using nvm please add the following to your .zshrc file and restart the terminal since the binaries of the file are not being detected by zsh shell we specify the path

```
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

Answer (score 35):

**Mac users only**
assuming you installed nvm prior, and npm correctly
(step-by-step guide below on how to install it:
[install nvm for Mac users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585261/nvm-keeps-forgetting-node-in-new-terminal-session/57024034#57024034)
).

you need to:

**Find the '.zshrc' file:**

- Open Terminal.
- Type `open ~` to access your home directory.
- Press `Cmd + Shift + .` to show the hidden files in Finder.
- Locate the **.zshrc**.

**Edit the '.zshrc' file:**

- add: `source /Users/_user_Name_/.bash_profile` to the top of the file (where _user_Name_ stands for your user.
- Save the file, and close the Terminal window.

Comment: Even though this may look like a hack, I find it to be a good way to bring in all of my pre-installed stuff from bash to a zsh after Catalina upgrade.

Comment: This, for me, is the answer, as simply running `source /Users/_user_Name_/.bash_profile` lasted only for the duration of the current session.

Comment: Just so it's clear, it looks like 'open ~' will open a new Finder window, which you could just open normally. And 'Cmd + Shift + .' is a toggle to hide/show hidden files. I believe the ability to view hidden files from Finder is a setting that has to be configured first, so maybe going through Terminal is the way around that. But if this setting has already been configured, it doesn't seem necessary to use Terminal to open Finder.

Comment: `.bash_profile` does not necessarily contain valid `zsh` code; `bash` and `zsh` are two similar, but distinct, shells.

Comment: In my case `.bash_profile` was `oh-my-zsh`. If anybody struggles with that.

Answer (score 27):

For **Mac** users:

Alongside the following:
nvm, iterm2, zsh

I found using the `.bashrc` rather than `.profile` or `.bash_profile` caused far less issues.

Simply by adding the latter to my `.zshrc` file:

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

Comment: I had to use `source $HOME/.bash_profile` but this is by far the best answer. I actually already had sdkman and node configured normally for bash. I added the node modules to the path but kept getting 'permission denied'.  This fixes that issue!  Back to coding!

Comment: If you are already configured bash for best use, then this is the best answer

Answer (score 23):

Go to your terminal and run: **nano .zshrc**

NOTE: If you don't have this file, you may create it using the 'touch' command:
**touch ~/.zshrc**

Paste the following anywhere below the line containing "export ZSH":

```
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

Now simply hit ^X and you will be asked if you would like to save. Say 'yes' and hit return, then hit return again if it says you are changing a file. You may need to restart your terminal after saving.

Try using **node -v** as a quick test if you've installed node before.

Comment: .zshrc is not a directory but a file, so if doesn't exists use `touch .zshrc` instead

Comment: Thank you, I will update change!

Comment: This answer should be marked as the correct answer, you saved my day

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad I was able to help :)  @TomVos

Answer (score 18):

On **Ubuntu**, after installing *ZSH*, and prevously on the `bash` terminal installed *Node* or other packages,

> First open:

`nano .zshrc`

> And uncomment the second line:

`export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

This works for me, and without writting any line, and I think this option is available on **Mac** too.

Comment: But this doesn't work for me. And even if I do add source $HOME/bin in my .zshrc it doesn't work. I get some output on the shell prompt every time I open it.

Comment: does not work on Mac OS

Answer (score 14):

For me the accepted answer for adding `export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH` to `.zshrc` didn't work. I tried adding the `NVM_DIR` as well which solved my issue.

1. Try `vi .bashrc`
2. You will find a line like the following. Copy it.

   `export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
   [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
   [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion`
3. Paste the copied content to `.zshrc` file
4. Restart the terminal

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: My situation: 1. I had installed Node via nvm, and everything was working. 2. Then in the meanwhile I switched from `bash` to `zsh`  and node. stopped working. So the above answer was the fix for me.

Answer (score 12):

Another thing to try and the answer for me was to uncomment the first `export` in `~/.zshrc`:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 11):

for **macOS** users: consider using `.profile` **instead** of `.bash_profile`. You may still need to manually add it to `~/.zshrc`:

```
source $HOME/.profile
```

**Note that there is no such file by default!** Quoting slhck https://superuser.com/a/473103:

> Anyway, you can simply create the file if it doesn't exist and open it in a text editor.
>
> ```
> touch ~/.profile
> open -e !$
> ```

The added value is that it feels good man to use a single file to set up the environment, regardless of the shell used. Loading a bash config file in zsh felt awkward.

Quoting an accepted answer by Cos https://stackoverflow.com/a/415444/2445063

> `.profile` is simply the login script filename originally used by `/bin/sh`. bash, being generally backwards-compatible with `/bin/sh`, will read `.profile` if one exists

Following Filip Ekberg's research / opinion https://stackoverflow.com/a/415410/2445063

> `.profile` is the equivalent of `.bash_profile` for the root. I think the name is changed to let other shells (csh, sh, tcsh) use it as well. (you don't need one as a user)

getting back to slhck, a **note of attention regarding bash**:

> (…) once you create a file called `~/.bash_profile`, your `~/.profile` will not be read anymore.

Comment: Just to add my 10 cents here, don't forget to do this AND close the terminal completely. Then open it again and it should work.
None of the solutions worked for me before quitting everything and reopen again. Perfect!

Comment: The best answer for me, as a Ubuntu user. I just needed to source the `.profile` file into my `.zshrc` file. Just add `source ~/.profile` at the start of the `.zshrc` file & reload & you should be ok.

Comment: this one did the trick for my due to using `volta` to install npm

Answer (score 11):

I solved this by `brew upgrade node`

Comment: This worked for me just now and should be anyone's first step before attempting to hard-modify system files as a follow-up step should this not work for you.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who is still having problem. Don't forget to logout and login again.

Answer (score 7):

In my humble opinion, first, you have to make sure you have any kind of Node version installed. For that type:

```
nvm ls
```

And if you don't get any versions it means I was right :) Then you have to type:

```
nvm install <node_version**>
```

** the actual version you can find in [Node website](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Then you will have Node and you will be able to use **npm commands**

Comment: Thanks @daxtersky. That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: This did it for me too.  node --version was different that `nvm ls` after running the command it is good now.

Answer (score 5):

In my case nvm seemed to have forgotten the global default - maybe some install i did since first adding it.

Simply re-aliasing did the trick:

```
nvm alias default [insert version number here]
```

Open a new terminal in order for this to take effect

Answer (score 4):

In my case, reinstalling node solved the issue. Anyone can install node via below website:

> https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: Reinstalling node js solves the problem because the nodejs' and npm's binary path are added to the PATH system variable as part of the setup. Reinstalling should be a last resort, setting npm path in zshrc or other solutions involving setting the path should be considered first.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me in zsh. Try `nvm install --latest-npm`

Comment: Why and how does it work? Is it a magic spell?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes simple things work. Uninstalling node and installing again worked for me.

```
brew uninstall node
brew install node
npm update
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by adding

```bash
    export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

    export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin/:$PATH"
```

in to   `.zshrc`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i installed node with NVM and after installing z Shell, node and nvm command didn't worked. So what worked for me was installing nvm again with this command :

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
sudo zsh install.sh
```

Above commands installed nvm again, since node was already installed, it added the node path automatically in .zshrc file and everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

Using Node v12+ on Mac Catalina, global dependencies are showing up in `/$HOME/.npm-global/bin`

Adding

```
export PATH="$HOME/.npm-global/bin:$PATH"
```

To `~/.bash_profile` to keep everything in one place, and then adding

`source $HOME/.bash_profile`

To `~/.zshrc` if it's not already there will do the trick. No need to logout and back in, just restart terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Add this at the end of your .zshrc file:

```
source $HOME/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh
```

This instantly solved my problem.

Comment: It works, but each time I checkout into other branches I need to run it again...

Answer (score 1):

FOR MAC: I tried some of the above but to no avail, could not get anything to work.

I did have BREW INSTALLED, so although this not be the best approach, with zsh, I did:

1. **sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/man/man8**  (for brew access)
2. **brew update && brew install npm**  (I had had node installed)
3. **npm -v**  (to confirm install)
4. **nano ~/.zshrc** (to empty file changes and save)

This worked for me.  Hope this helps someone.  #1 bothers me, but I will live with for now.

Answer (score 1):

Just writing this in my terminal fixed the issue. Note that I had to write it separately in my project folder.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH"
```

Source: https://cloudlinuxtech.com/npm-command-not-found-fix/

Answer (score 1):

I got this message after installing using Homebrew

[image]

So I added these lines to the `.zshrc` and it worked.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@16/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/node@16/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/node@16/include"
```

Answer (score 1):

no need to install node again if u have installed it via nvm, just paste following in your .zshrc file.

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  
 # This   loads nvm bash_completion
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is more about the ZSH completion.

You need to add this line in your .zshrc:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' rehash true
```

If you have Oh-my-zsh, a PR has been made, you can integrate it until it is pulled: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/3440

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while installing Vercel CLI.

In my case, install with `sudo`.

example: `sudo npm i -g vercel`

Answer (score 0):

For **OSX** *Catalina* users

```
brew install node@14
```

I'm using node 14 cause angular won't support latest version (Don't know why)..
Then

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: I’ve heard Brew is not ideal for production environments because it may cause issues with company security policies. I would not recommend this unless it is your personal machine.

Comment: Thanks  @Shah I'll keep this in mind, never thought that brew has some security issues. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It’s not Brew, it’s more so that your company may not give permissions for certain actions

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened after I configured my iterm2 to show git branch names. I basically made my iterm2 to look more elegant. But I noticed my vscode terminal was detecting nvm and npm commands

I have added some lines to  .zshrc file when I am configuring iterm2. I had added oh-my-zsh.

But adding the below line to the top of .zshrc file worked for me. If it does not work kill vscode terminal and open it again

Hope this will help someone

```html
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Windows** using windows-nvm I had issues after installing an additional version of node. My npm stopped working but only in ZSH. bash, Powershell, and cmd all worked fine. What ended up fixing it was adding an additional alias to zsh of `alias npm="npm.cmd"` and it started working again. I think it's zsh struggling to find the correct binary, so the .cmd file fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had node installed with nvm, and the issue i had is that i had 2 versions of node, and i used them with command nvm use v12.xx.0. But somehow they both got detached, and i had to use it again with nvm one of them, and it started to work again how it should.
So the command is(if you have at least one version installed with nvm):

> nvm use vxx.xx.0

Answer (score 0):

I had zsh shell and Node installed along with `npmrc`. I had been using it for years when suddenly it started giving me this error. None of the answers here helped me with this problem.

Turns out I had recently updated my Node version and I had to install [npmrc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npmrc) again. So if anyone is having this problem after upgrading their node version, try

`npm install -g npmrc`