# How to pipe from NodeJS to NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, bash, pipe, stdout, stdin

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
node x.js | node y.js
```

The file x.js is just printing a string:

```
console.log("hi");
```

The file y.js is intended to get that string "hi" via `process.stdin` and do something with it.

But it does not work. zsh (my shell) throws this error: `zsh: command not found:  node`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me. `$ node hi.js | grep -rn "hi"` with output `(standard input):1:hi`. Maybe show us your `y.js` file?

Comment: Actually do you have `node` installed?

Comment: Yes. Node is installed. Just calling `node x.js` prints "hi" successfully.

Comment: @KentShikama `node hi.js | grep -rn "hi"` also works for me. It does not seem to matter what's in the second file. If it's empty, it does not work. If it's tries to get stdin from `process.stdin.on`, it does not work...

Comment: Sounds like a PATH problem, maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743928/command-not-found-after-npm-install-in-zsh) can help.

Comment: What happens when you do `echo hi | node y.js`?

Comment: Fascinating... How about `node x.js && node y.js` and `node x.js | which node`

Comment: First one: result is "hi" but it runs forever because y.js seems to wait for stdin.

Comment: Second one: it returns "/usr/local/bin/node".

Comment: I'm so confused right now... It's working now. The same command `node x.js | node y.js` prints "hi".... and I don't know why. The solution of @KentShikama also works now.....

Comment: It’s mysterious what went on there

Answer (score 0):

It does matter what is in the second file. You need to read from stdin. Try the following.

```
$ cat hi.js 
console.log("hi");

$ cat read.js 
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', function(line){
    console.log(line);
})

$ node hi.js | node read.js
hi
```

Comment: I tried it, but still: `zsh: command not found:  node`. I don't understand why node can't be found when I pipe something to it. I installed node via brew (MacOS) by the way.