# Why am I receiving the following error message? zsh: command not found: npm

Tags: reactjs

Sorry I'm new to developing and there's a lot of stuff that I don't really understand 100% yet. I'm trying to configure VSC but when I enter the following command into the terminal:

> paulnewby@iMac ~ % npm install -g create-react-app

it throws up an error message:

> zsh: command not found: npm.

I'm not sure what zsh is (Wikipedia's description is a little jargon heavy for a novice developer) but apparently Mac OS Catalina (which I am using) has it by default. I believe I have node / npm installed, but I may have done this incorrectly. Does anyone have any knowledge as to why this error is occurring/what zsh is/ how I can fix it? This would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: do you have `node` installed

Comment: i think `npm` isn't installed, check that with `npm -v`

Answer (score 1):

`zsh` is short for "Z Shell", which is the default shell used by MacOS. To say it short: A shell is a program run by a terminal, to execute commands, manage command line history and [much more](https://superuser.com/a/144668).

When you say you already installed NPM, then your shell (`zsh`) does not know about that yet. You should check again if you correctly installed [nodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and maybe check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15692703/6419859) to help `zsh` to recognize your NPM installation:

> If you installed Node.js using Homebrew, npm binaries can be found in /usr/local/share/npm/bin. You should make sure this directory is in your PATH environment variable. So, in your ~/.zshrc file add export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH.