# "sh: node: command not found error" in npm postinstall in zsh

Tags: npm, sh, gatsby, zsh, nvm

I use `zsh` as the default command-line shell. I have installed `node` using `nvm`.

When I try to install GatsbyJS I get an error

```
npm i -g gatsby-cli
....
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /Users/username/~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/postinstall.js
npm ERR! sh: node: command not found
```

It seems like gatsby-cli trying to run `postinstall.js` script with `node` in `sh` shell, but it is not available there because my nvm/node declared in `.zshrc`.

I was able to run nvm and node in `sh` by creating a `.profile` file like:

```
export NVM_DIR="~/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

But I need to run `source ~/.profile` for each `sh` session, otherwise, it doesn't work. As post-install generates a new `sh` session I can't force it to use `.profile`.

I'm not strong in all this shell stuff, so any help appreciated.

(Note: I have no such problems with installing other npm packages e.g. webpack-cli)

Comment: You should consider filing a bug report with the repo

Comment: I'll give a chance to StackOverflow masters. If there is no my mistake I'll create an issue on github. But Gatsby is a pretty popular package and no-one complains, so it's most likely my fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in nvm installation.

Steps to fix:

1. Edit `.zshrc` as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59833769/7964409)
2. Re-install node via nvm