# Can't enable 256 colors in ConEmu

Tags: terminal, conemu, ansi-colors, 256color

I'm trying to get 256 colors in the fantastic [ConEmu-Maximus5](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/) console.

**Update:** Now it only shows 8 colors. I know because '$tput colors' output is '8'

I have followed the [instructions](http://translate.google.ru/translate?hl=ru&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/AnsiEscapeCodes?show=content) and activated:

- TrueMod (24-bit color) support
- Inject ConEmuHk
- ANSI x3.64 / xterm 256 colors

I don't understand what to do with '*check off whether the buffer / slide.*'

- I'm in windows 7.
- I start ConEmu with a custom direct link, so it loads cygwin bash file.

```
"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" /cmd ""C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe" --login -i"
```

- In my bashrc profile I have -> export TERM=cygwin
- This is my custom command prompt:

```
    function prompt {

    local RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
    local GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
    local COOLRED="\e[38;5;173m"
    local COOLGREEN="\e[38;5;113m"
    PS1="$COOLRED\u@\h $LIGHT_COOLGREEN\$PWD \[\e[0m\] > "

    }

    prompt
```

- The value of ConEmuANSI in ON, by the way.

I have some screen shots:

[image]

As you can see the command prompt looks very extravagant because it doesn't like the 256 color settings. If i substitute the variables COOLRED and COOLGREEN with RED and GREEN, then it looks ok, but it's not 256 colors.

More screenshots of the settings:

[image]
[image]

And the last sceen shot it's cygwin's mintty. Everything is ok there. Full 256 color supported. It's a shame mintty doesn't have tabs. That's mostly the reason why I'm trying to move to ConEmu.

[image]

Thank you very much for helping!!!

Comment: Explain to the nub ;) What file should I create in bash to redefine prompt?

Comment: Just create a file called .bashrc in your home directory

Comment: Weird. ".bashrc" does not working, but ".profile" do.

Comment: More weird. Bash does not send Esc to console, but rather it trying to process them itself. Here you are - 8 colors.

Comment: This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment) explains about .bashrc .bash_profile and .profile

Comment: Does ConEmu now support 256 colors?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bash does not send ANSI sequences to console. It tries to process them itself. And, because *nix terminal is generally only 8-color (not taking into account 256-color mode), bash uses 8-color palette instead of 16-color palette which is common to Windows terminal.

I think, 256-colors works in mintty because `_isatty` returns zero in that terminal. But it returns non zero value under ConEmu. May be in future builds I solve this puzzle (how to create real terminal with PTY features for some applications).

**As for the question**

You have no need in 256-colors In fact. To redefine prompt palette you may use "Extend foreground colors with background" feature. In breaf - set up colors 16, 17, etc. in ConEmu, set prompt background in bash to #5 (configurable in ConEmu), and voila.

There was a small bug in ConEmu "Extend..." processing. Use build 121016 or later.

```
PS1="\e[30;45m\u@\h \e[34;45m$PWD \[\e[0m\] > "
```

[image: ConEmu and real console window]

[image: ConEmu settings]

**Following info does not match the question, but may be useful**

Current version does not support 256-color mode in 'whole' console buffer (limitation, yes, removing it in plans).

So, you can go 2 ways

- totally disable scrollback buffer (many ways, for example "cmd -cur_console:h0")
- work in the bottom of the scroll-buffer.

Comment: Thanks for your hard work. It's true I don't really need 256 colors. I just need about 16 good looking ones, and I can do that in the colors section. Cheers!

Comment: @Maximus I would be happy to see 256 colours in ConEmu - I want to be able to see full capacitly of LS_COLORS for example

Comment: `Bash does not send ANSI codes to the console` could you elaborate on this? Because afaik that is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I also couldn't get 256 color support to work (the colors would show up, but they looked the same as the 16-color palette).  I switched to the "xterm" color scheme and now it works in native Windows executables (such as Python) but not in anything that uses Cygwin.  Cygwin appears to have terminal-escape-sequence processing that you can't turn off, which defeats the `ConEmuHk` injection.

[This is documented on the ConEmu wiki, here.](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/CygwinAnsi)

Answer (score 1):

I had this weird problem and the weird solution and somehow it works. and don't know if this is with others too, just some info-sharing in case this shall be helpful.

I like colouring my consoles and like to utilize the full real 256 bits of RGB colouring.
After confuguring as in the conemu/CMDer (i used the forked one) [instruction](https://conemu.github.io/en/Xterm256Colors.html). my 256bit coloring test looked like this.[image]. After mucking around a bit and testing with my bash 256bit capability. i.e running this command:

```
for i in {1..16384}; do echo -en "\e[38;5;${i}mTest";done
```

*note supposed to be {1..256}, but i had to force it for a longer colour prints, so just took a longer random number..
giving the result:
[image]

But running some 2-3 times, i saw this clean gray shade suddenly
[image]

and it worked then on..
[image]

weird but i got this working. Could it be that CMDer is somehow not using the full 256 bit because of optimizing reason and it get triggered when it is kicked in??,

PS: my CMDer cmd for the console:

```
-cur_console:fp -cur_console:d:"C:\WS":P:"<Cobalt>":t:"test":C:"C:\Arbeit\tools\Iconka-Buddy-Ninja.ico" set "PATH=%ConEmuDrive%\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;%PATH%" & "%ConEmuDrive%\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --no-cd --command=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-msys2-64.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i
```

Answer (score -1):

```
local COOLRED="\e[38;5;173m"

local COOLGREEN="\e[38;5;113m"
```

Those `\e`s are probably from an e.g. C `printf` string. You don't want them in a shell script. Stick with the original `\033` notation. Also you are missing the closing `\]`. These lines should now read

```
local COOLRED="\[\033[38;5;173m\]"

local COOLGREEN="\[\033[38;5;113m\]"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your variables, but still no luck. I've tried removing my custom color prompt, just in case, and when I print AnsiColors256.ans looks like it only can display 8 colors.

Comment: `\e` is usually analogous to the escape character and **are indeed** required. They have nothing to do with `printf`.