# How to enable 256 colors in ConEmu

Tags: windows, vim, conemu

I want to use vim in 256 color mode (for the solarized color scheme) on Windows 8 with ConEmu. How can I do this?

Currently, when I run solarized vim with 256 colors with ConEmu, it looks like this:
[image]

I can also run this in 32 color mode (with vimrc):
[image]

My ConEmu settings:

- Inject ConEmuHk
- ANSI X3.64 / xterm 256 colors

UPDATE:
I've inserted the extra lines suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14434531/1696114). Now the colorscheme seems to be somewhat working, but there are side-effects. I get a washout color over blocks of text that I've moved the cursor down over, and a brown where the cursor has moved up. Note that I am using the plugin pack [spf13](http://vim.spf13.com/), so this could be an issue with another plugin.

[image: after trying extra lines in vimrc]

Comment: The solarized colorscheme doesn't work well with 256 colors. Use `xterm` or a similar `TERM` and set your terminal emulator's default palette to the solarized colors.

Comment: You haven't shown your vimrc color settings

Comment: possible duplicate of [ConEmu: Vim Syntax Highlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315519/conemu-vim-syntax-highlight)

Comment: @Maximus: Post is updated now with a view of relevant vimrc settings.@MatthewStrawbridge I've tried this answer, see the results in my update

Comment: solarized scheme for vim has some strange problems. There are many conditions inside... For example zenburn is working properly.

Comment: @Maximum Yes, Zenburn and some other does work for me, but not all. Thanks.