# VIM missing cursor in both insert and command mode

Tags: vim

Recently I found out that my vim doesn't show any cursor when I try to edit something or when I'm typing in commands.

I'm using windows 7 64bit with ConEmu and cygwin, however since cygwin's vim doesn't pass ANSI to ConEmu, which I needed in order to make some color schemes work on vim. I have downloaded the win32 console version on the official vim site and replaced the cygwin vim.exe with this one. As of now I am using version 7.4 of vim.exe.
I downloaded the win32 console executable.

In the screenshot below you can see that the cursor is missing. I've also opened up my .vimrc so you can see if there is anything that might be causing this. I thought it might have something to do with my current color scheme but even without a color scheme vim acts like it doesn't have a cursor.

[VIM screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRR3W.jpg)

EDIT: So what I'm trying to do is to get the 256-color console working in ConEmu. The colors are indeed working. However, the cursor starts to dissapear when I'm using the setup suggested on this site: http://conemu.github.io/en/VimXterm.html. I have very little understanding of what is going on and would love to see anyone come up with a solution as to why this is.
My .vimrc looks like this:

```
let $VIM=/usr/share/vim/vim74
let $VIMRUNTIME=/usr/share/vim/vim74
execute pathogen#infect()
set nocompatible
set mouse=a
inoremap <Esc>[62~ <C-X><C-E>
inoremap <Esc>[63~ <C-X><C-Y>
nnoremap <Esc>[62~ <C-E>
nnoremap <Esc>[63~ <C-Y>
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
set number
silent! nmap <C-p> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
silent! map <F3> :NERDTreeFind<CR>
let g:NERDTreeMapActivateNode="<F3>"
let g:NERDTreeMapPreview="<F4>"
let g:NERDTreeShowHidden=1

if !has("gui_running")
    set termencoding=utf8
    set term=xterm
    set t_Co=256
    let &t_AB="\e[48;5;%dm"
    let &t_AF="\e[38;5;%dm"
    colorscheme badwolf
endif
```

So far I've downloaded vim-airline in order to see my cursor position but still, this isn't ideal.

EDIT 2: doesn't this have something to do with Control Sequence Initiator codes?
Perhaps CSI ?25l is sent and I should try to send CSI ?25h instead? I have no clue as to how this can be accomplished tho...

Comment: Try removing lines which start with silent from vimrc. You can also try removing lines one by one to see if one of them is causing that

Comment: I found out it had something to do with setting the terminal to xterm. Whenever I commented out that line it started to work. However, if I don't supply the term variable with xterm I'm unable to see my color scheme and it shows all the escape characters in my vim...

Comment: Maybe the xterm has that behavior by default?

Comment: I would find it rather odd not to have a cursor as default behaviour but still. My problem right now is that I don't know what I have to supply to my term variable in order to make everything work properly, or perhaps provide the xterm to it and find a workaround for the missing cursor.

Right now I'm trying out all diferent possible terminal values.

Comment: ok so apparently the following seem to have the same behaviour as 
xterm:
amiga, beos-ansi, ansi, pcansi, vt320, iris-ansi, dumb
the other ones show a completely unorganized screen with all sorts of escape sequences and is really messy. I still have no clue how to get vim to work the way I want it to...

Comment: Update your question with your new research you mentioned in comments so that someone can help you

Comment: Here is a reference as to what I'm trying to accomplish: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315519/conemu-vim-syntax-highlight/14434531#14434531 
http://conemu.github.io/en/VimXterm.html