# Rails starting terminal type in source all the time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

I'm new to this rails thing, I was wondering if every time I start up the terminal, do I need to type in

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

I'm using ubuntu by the way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to type this thing in all the time. You should have some code within your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` which sources this script for you automatically.

Comment: I'm sorry for extending this question, but can you explain a bit more about what those are? Thanks!

Comment: @andrewliu, i find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment there are some good answers here.

Comment: NewB answered it better than I could :)