# Ubuntu add directory to Python path

Tags: python, ubuntu, importerror

I want to run third part tool written in python on my ubuntu machine ([corgy tool](https://github.com/pkerpedjiev/corgy)).

However I don't know how to add additional modules to Python path.

```
cat doc/download.rst         
There is currently no setup.py, so you need to manually add
the download directory to your PYTHON_PATH environment variable.
```

How can I add directory to PYTHON_PATH?

**I have tried:**
`export PYTHON_PATH=/home/user/directory:$PYTHON_PATH && source .bashrc`
`export PATH=/home/user/directory:$PATH && source .bashrc`

`python

 import sys

 sys.path.append("/home/user/directory/")`

But when I try to run this tool I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "examples/dotbracket_to_bulge_graph.py", line 4, in <module>
import corgy.graph.bulge_graph as cgb
ImportError: No module named corgy.graph.bulge_graph
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a `.bash_profile` in your home directory. Then, add the line

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:new_dir
EXPORT $PYTHONPATH
```

Or even better:

```
if [ -d "new_dir" ] ; then
  PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:new_dir"
fi
EXPORT $PYTHONPATH
```

The `.bash_profile` properties are loaded every time you log in.

The `source` command is useful if you don't want to log in again.

Comment: could you explain how this is different from the export call?

Comment: @njzk2 `export` just sets the variable for your current session. This should also work but only until you log out. And `source`ing `.bashrc` of course makes no sense.

Comment: And, what is more important, you _have to use `export`_ when setting variables in `.bash_profile`.

Comment: There is a nice explanation in http://stackoverflow.com/q/415403/1983854 . I did not know it is necessary to `EXPORT`  in bash_profile. I update my answer accordingly.

Comment: that's my point. If it doesn't work with a simple export, i don't see how adding it the bash_profile helps. unless the script spawns a new session

Answer (score 5):

[@fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui-so-stop-harming)'s answer above was almost good for me, but there is at least one mistake (I am not sure about the `export` statement in all caps, I am a complete newbie).
There should not be a `$` sign preceding PYTHONPATH in the export statement. So the options would be:

> Create a .bash_profile in your home directory. Then, add the line
>
> ```
> PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:new_dir
> export PYTHONPATH
> ```
>
> Or even better:
>
> ```
> if [ -d "new_dir" ] ; then
>   PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:new_dir"
> fi
> export PYTHONPATH
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
sudo ln -s /your/path/to/python /usr/local/bin/python
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**