# mprof python memory_profiler

Tags: python, memory-profiling

I installed memory_profiler on my system and ran this program

```
!/usr/bin/env python
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile(precision=4)
def my_func():
    a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
    b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
   del b
   return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
   my_func()
```

after running python fp.py
it displayed

```
Filename: fp.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4  12.6992 MiB   0.0000 MiB   @profile(precision=4)
     5                             def my_func():
     6  20.3516 MiB   7.6523 MiB       a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
     7 172.8945 MiB 152.5430 MiB       b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
     8  20.5273 MiB -152.3672 MiB       del b
     9  20.5273 MiB   0.0000 MiB       return a
```

but while running mprof run fp.py it returns

```
No command 'mprof' found, did you mean:
 Command 'sprof' from package 'libc-dev-bin' (main)
 Command 'mlprof' from package 'mlton-tools' (universe)
 Command 'pprof' from package 'tau' (universe)
 Command 'prof' from package 'profphd' (universe)
 Command 'gprof' from package 'binutils' (main)
 Command 'gprof' from package 'binutils-multiarch' (main)
mprof: command not found
```

how should i plot the memory usage graph is there any other library.

Comment: Did you install memory_profiler via pip?

Comment: Also, you must use this command in your system command prompt, not in a python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

You've to run `mprof run filename.py`, `mprof plot` commands on terminal.

For reference, visit this page [Performance analysis of your python program using Memory_Profiler](https://medium.com/@sonia_samipillai/performance-analysis-of-your-python-program-using-memory-profiler-fa9ea83fe3cd)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has something to do with PATH.

Depends on the linux distribution, executables from pip can be installed at different locations.

For ubuntu, it is very likely in the following locations:

- /usr/local/bin/mprof
- ~/.local/bin/mprof (if it was installed as user package, i.e. by `pip3 install memory-profiler --user`)

You can either add it into PATH (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913086/ubuntu-add-directory-to-python-path)) or run the script with full path (i.e. `/usr/local/bin/mprof run fp.py`)