# What are these warning? How to fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, virtualenv, pipenv

This shows me warnings when I try to install PIPENV.

Click on this link for the screenshot ⬇

Warnings:
[image]

How to fix the warnings? How to set the path?

```
pip3 install pipenv
Collecting pipenv
  Downloading pipenv-2020.11.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.9 MB 655 kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=18.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pipenv) (20.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pipenv) (45.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from pipenv) (20.4.0)
Collecting virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5
  Downloading virtualenv_clone-0.5.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pipenv) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.14.0)
Installing collected packages: virtualenv-clone, pipenv
  WARNING: The script virtualenv-clone is installed in '/home/papan/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts pipenv and pipenv-resolver are installed in '/home/papan/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pipenv-2020.11.15 virtualenv-clone-0.5.4
```

Comment: The warnings literally give you two options to fix it - what are you really trying to ask?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: I've added a screenshot if it's visible to you Yatin,This is exactly similar to the long non-structure error message added by me earlier, I tried to make it cleaner nothing else.

Comment: I can't see how I'm vandalizing my post here.

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually a problem as it says `Successfully installed pipenv-2020.11.15 virtualenv-clone-0.5.4`

Comment: @PapanSarkar use the `--no-warn-script-location.`

Comment: this is to suppress but i want to fix the path

Comment: @PapanSarkar consider using the other option then.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
pip3 install pipenv
```

the module will be installed for the current user and wouldn't be added to system path. If you want to install the module for whole system(in simple don't want that warning) use:

```
sudo pip3 install pipenv
```

It didn't gave me warning when i did this.
And if you literally want to add that folder to path then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913086/ubuntu-add-directory-to-python-path#16913180) will be helpful.