# alias hello='echo Hello' - why doesn't this work after a restart?

Tags: bash

All over the internet you see this commands

```
alias hello='echo Hello'
```

Yes, I know the above is a lame example, but it's beside the point. If I execute that, it works. But when I restart my computer, it is lost. Why? a bug with the alias command? Why would it only work until a restart is executed?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will need to write it into your `~/.bashrc` like

```
echo "alias hello='echo hello'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

This appends the string to your `.bashrc` and will be read when you start a `bash` in xterm or even pure command line.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. But what is the point of the Alias command if it doesn't remember anything? By itself, it seems a dumb command :/

Comment: You are welcome. It will be remembered as long as your bash-session is valid. This is why there is `.bashrc` to make your bash "remember" after power-off ;)

Comment: So is ~/.profile and ~/.bash_profile just used to store variables? and ~/.bashrc for aliases? Like currently in mine, I use the export VAR=Var_value command to remember a var.

Comment: Have a look at `~/.bashrc` using `less` or `cat`; there is usually some other stuff in there. You can put all `bash`-relevant stuff in there, like environment-variables or define scripts.

Comment: There's nothing in mine (using OSX, that might be why). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment told me though. Thanks for your answer, no more re-typing alias commands :)

Comment: @Nadine Yes, bash is not that important on OSX, as for example on Linux. Now you can spent these typed characters somewhere else :)

Comment: this answer did not work any more in my MACBOOK AIR.