# workon command not found when using fabric

Tags: python, bash, fabric

My fabric file:

```
def deploy():
   code_path = 'mysite/public_html/mysite'
   with cd(code_path):
      with prefix("workon mysite"):
         run('git pull')
         run('supervisorctl -c ~/supervisord.conf restart ' + env.host_string)
```

I get the following error:

```
Aborting.
[myserv] out: /bin/bash: workon: command not found
```

Obviously workon command works when I do this manually (without fabric). I suspect `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` is not being sourced (it normally gets run through .bash_profile).

What do I need to do to get `workon` command working?

Comment: Have you tried running the workon cmd on the machine you are running the fabric command on with the same user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try modifying your prefix with:

```
  with prefix(". /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh; workon mysite"):
```

Comment: Thanks for this usefull info. I'd even say `with prefix('. /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh'):` then `with prefix('workon project'):`

Comment: Ok, it works but does not explain why it does not work by default. For myself, bashrc gets executed but no workon command is available. That's odd.

Answer (score 3):

you have to copy this virtualwrapper load code from `.bashrc` to `.bash_profile` file or if not exist create new `.bash_profile` file and copy there.

code to copy::

```
export WORKON_HOME=/home/virtual
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

this error happen because `.bashrc` is only read by a shell that's both interactive and non-login. So in this case it is not interactive non-login shell, so it won't work. so we have to copy those code to `.bash_profile` file.

[reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment/415444#415444)

Answer (score 0):

I use pyenv with plugin pyenv-virtualenvwrapper. I had no success with workon, instead I use this (fabric 2.5):

```
with c.prefix('source /home/mirek/.virtualenvs/%s/bin/activate' % PROJECT):
    with c.prefix('cd /home/mirek/dj/%s/%s' % (PROJECT, PROJECT)):
        c.run('python manage.py ....')
```