# is there a way to combine EOF with a terminal alias?

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, ssh, terminal

I am relatively new to using the command line.

I want to create an alias such as "importme" that will do the following:

```
alias importme="ssh root@server.com << EOF
mysql
list databases;
EOF"
```

The problem is that using EOF requires pressing ENTER, which is not possible with alias'.  My end goal is to create an alias that will import a database into a REMOTE database server from my local machine.

Any ideas on how to create this alias? with or without using EOF? Thanks

Comment: interestingly enough, with my zsh this works. it fails horribly with bash, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead, create a function an save it in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
importme()
{
   ssh root@server.com << EOF
mysql
list databases;
EOF
}
```

Source (`. ~/.bashrc`) and you will be ready to use it with `importme`.

Comment: thanks fedorqui! is there any harm in putting this in ~/.profile instead?

Comment: @Rees to be honest, I always have to check in http://stackoverflow.com/a/415444/1983854 to guess it. I would use `.bashrc`, but try and `.profile` should make it. And if you don't mind, come back and explain so we both learn it!