# How to make OS X to read .bash_profile not .profile file

Tags: macos, bash

I have read so many suggestions about, not putting your customization aka commands in ".profile" file. Rather, create a .bash_profile for yourself and add your alias and etc.

But,when I open the new terminal, if there is only .bash_profile, OS X is not exporting/sourcing the commands mentioned in it. I have to manually source the .bash_profile.

If I create .profile file, on opening a new terminal, all my commands in .profile are executed  and will be available readily.

Could you please help me in understanding, how does it works? Also, when to use .bashrc/.profile/.bash_profile files.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment

Comment: Are you sure you are using bash, and not some other shell? Try `echo $SHELL`

Answer (score 92, accepted):

According to the manual page that ships with OS X:

> ... it looks for **`~/.bash_profile`**, **`~/.bash_login`**, and **`~/.profile`**, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The **`--noprofile`** option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

It should only read `~/.profile` as a last resort if neither `~/.bash_profile` nor `~/.bash_login` are readable.

On all of my OS X systems, I have my `~/.bash_profile` set to:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

It is highly recommended that you do this on OS X in order to get bash to read your `~/.bashrc` file like you would expect.

Comment: I had the same problem with command aliases in `~/.profile` not being put into effect in Terminal, and fixed the problem by using your method of moving the commands into `~/.bashrc` (and deleting `~/.profile` and making the little `~/.bash_profile`). However, now when I execute `echo $PATH` all my path entries appear twice in the output. So something's still wrong!

Comment: weird. had `.bash_profile` and terminal.app is ignoring it here. moved the file (kept all the same permissions) to `.profile` and now it is happy.

Comment: Reminder if you are using `zsh` instead of `bash`. The terminal will source `.zshrc` instead of `.bash_profile`.

Comment: As of today, the default terminal shell in OSX Cataline is `zsh`, so @AlbertSamuel's comment is should be turned into an answer.

Comment: @AlbertSamuel Thanks! Just got a new mac and this solved it

Answer (score 116):

According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050),

> zsh (Z shell) is the default shell for all newly created user accounts, starting with macOS Catalina.

So you should verify your default shell with the command:

```
$ echo $SHELL
```

If the result is */bin/bash* your default shell is BASH, and if the result is */bin/zsh* the default is ZSH.

Go to home with `$ cd ~/` and create the profile (if it does not exist) and edit it with the commands:

For bash:

```
$ touch .bash_profile
$ open .bash_profile
```

For ZSH:

```
$ touch .zprofile
$ open .zprofile
```

Comment: You are a hero. I've been trying to figure out why .bash_profile/.bashrc/.profile don't work for half an hour.

Comment: Thanks!! Z shell threw me for a loop and googling turns up all of the older methods...

Comment: thanks man! I used a mac after 4 years and you saved me. i was stuck with bash_profile

Comment: For Apple M1 chip, this one worked. Look no further, thank you Doug.!

Comment: Thank you @Doug for your answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is crazy I guess my original mac account was created pre-catalina and was using the typical .bash_profile.  I recently ran into login issues, and my user account was recreated on Big Sur which I currently run. I was able to fix my env variables issues by
"cd ~/" then "cp .bash_profile .zprofile"

Answer (score 59):

It's also possible that your terminal shell is defaulting to sh instead of bash. You can verify this first:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/tcsh
```

To change this to bash, you can go into your Terminal -> Preferences -> Startup tab, and change "Shell Opens With:" from "Default login shell" to Command and value "/bin/bash".

Alternately, you can change your default shell by executing the following command at the command prompt:

```
chsh -s bin/bash
```

After you do one of these, open a new shell window, and your .bash_profile should be sourced.

Comment: I found that I wanted to use sh instead of bash. I use zsh and I found this comment to be helpful: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/3807#issuecomment-187930190 - basically add `source ~/.bash_profile` to the bottom of your `~/.zshrc` config

Comment: Yes, that work!  Just, add `source ~/.bash_profile` to the bottom of your `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Add source ~/.bash_profile to the bottom of your ~/.zshrc.
This should be an answer

Answer (score 21):

For anyone else who finds this, instead of bash_profile, for new versions of mac you can use `.zshrc`. I.E., do

```
open .zshrc
```

and add what you need there.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `zsh` to fix the problem.

> The Z shell (also known as `zsh`) is a Unix shell that is built on top
>   of `bash` (the default shell for macOS) with additional features. It's
>   recommended to use `zsh` over `bash.`

**Installation**

1. Install zsh using Homebrew: `$ brew install zsh`
2. Install Oh My Zsh: `$ sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`
3. Move to `.bash_profile` setting `.zshrc` file
4. To apply the changes you make you need to either start new shell
   instance or run: `source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: FYI bash is no longer the default shell for macOS (as of Catalina)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using zsh, you can source to .bash_profile by adding the following line to .zprofile

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
    source ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be mentioned that bash will first look for a `/etc/profile` file, as stated in the Bash man pages.

> When  bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-inter-
>   active shell with the --login option, **it first reads and executes  com-
>   mands  from  the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.**  After reading
>   that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
>   in  that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that
>   exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be  used  when  the
>   shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

Comment: That `bash` on OSX by default doesn't source `~/.bashrc` is unrelated to any content in `/etc/profile`. Rather, it has to do with the fact that `Terminal.app` creates _every_ bash shell as a _login_ session, so that only `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile` (whichever is found fist) are sourced. If you want `~/.bashrc` to be sourced too, source it explicitly from `~/.bash_profile`, as in @Andon M. Coleman's answer. (If you explicitly start a bash session as an _interactive NON-login session_, `~/.bashrc` gets sourced automatically.)

Comment: You are absolutely right, and I posted my explanation too hastily. Thank your for the correction; I edited my answer and upvoted your comment as it explains correctly what I had attempted to describe.

Comment: On OSX El Capitan, I noticed that root runs under /bin/sh (I believe that's the Ash shell?) instead of the Bash shell. But when I open a terminal prompt and check the $SHELL var, it reads /bin/bash. So, what script do we edit for the case of /bin/sh?

Answer (score -4):

I solved by simply adding `bash` (in a newline) into ~/.bash_profile file.