# MAMP PRO 6 command line shortcut not working

Tags: php, macos, mamp, macos-big-sur, mamp-pro

**Hello** and **thank you** for taking your time to read this! Now to get straight to the point, I am using **MAMP PRO 6** for school and recently we had to install **Composer** through the terminal. Upon closer inspection `php -v` revealed that I am not using the MAMP's php version   with **Xdebug** but rather the pre-installed php version that comes with macOS. I have enabled `Activate command line shortcuts for the selected PHP version, pear & pecl` but this is not working. I'm on the latest **Big Sur** update and looking for a possible fix.

**MAMP PRO is working with the exception of command line shortcut.**

Comment: You can read this documentation how to install mamp on mac os  https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-Mac/Installation/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But this is not the issue mamp pro is installed and mostly working with the exception of command line shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that my .profile is not being loaded automatically , current workaround is doing `source ~/.profile` and then confirming the location and version with `which php` and `php -v`.

**Update: This did it for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/56236178/14612433**

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the shell you use (bash, zsh, check your OS) just add "source ~/.profile" to your bash, zsh-or other profile. MAMP PRO 6 recreates the .profile when changing php versions.
Check the "composer"-link in the UI and everything should work just fine. Don't forget to start a new terminal session though. Otherwise the old configuration (with the old php and more) stays active.

~/.profile is not being read. You have to define a ~/.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc or something. In that profile that is read by the shell you put the "source"-statement.