# Cannot find true $PATH file on Mavericks

Tags: php, path, bash, .profile, mamp-pro

I have both `~/.bash_profile` & `~/.profile` files.

`~/.bash_profile` contains one line:

```
export PATH=/Applications/mamp/bin/php5.5.3/bin:$PATH
```

`~/.profile` contains three lines:

```
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-02-02_at_20:54:53: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.5.3/bin/:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

As you can see I am trying to get my default PHP PATH to use MAMPs PHP because I have mcrypt installed on it. For some reason when I type `whereis PHP` I get the native route: `/usr/bin/php`, and when I `echo $PATH` I get:

```
/Applications/mamp/bin/php5.5.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Somewhere I have another file thats really controlling my PATH and I have no clue where it is. What else could be controlling my PATH route?

**NOTE:** I have *Homebrew*, *MacPorts*, *Xcode*, and *Xcode Command-Line Tools* installed.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is coming from the system-wide /etc/paths file. It is the source of the base $PATH environment variable before ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile and others get involved. If you're in a Terminal window, you can edit it with the following command:

```
sudo open -t /etc/paths
```

By default it contains the following paths:

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

I wouldn't recommend editing this file, however, because it is system-wide and will affect every user on the system.

If you want complete control over $PATH, so as to affect only your own account you're probably better off just *not* including $PATH in your .profile's export PATH lines. For example (but not this):

```
export PATH=/Applications/mamp/bin/php5.5.3/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `.profile` is being loaded? Try a test and add an echo line to it:

```
echo "test: .profile has loaded"
```

Now open a new terminal window, do you see your echo? I suspect not as I don't think OSX loads `.profile` by default, at least today.

If you really want to use `.profile` you can ask `.bash_profile` to load it:

```
if [ -f ~/.profile ]; then
    source ~/.profile
fi
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit**:
Looks like .profile is loaded, if no .bash_profile or .bash_login exist as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18773150/1565992)