# zshenv:2: command not found: rbenv

Tags: ruby, terminal, zsh, rbenv

I've just had a nightmare getting rbenv to load Ruby v 2.3.0. I've finally got it to show after adding 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"'to my .zshrc file. However, now I'm getting the note above at the top of my terminal when I relaunch.
Any ideas why this would show and how I can amend?

Comment: What does "the note" say? I have exactly the same line in my `.zshrc` and don't really recall it being a nightmare, rather a mundane documentation-following.

Comment: It wasn't the .zshrc file that was the issue it was the same line in the .zshenv which I've now deleted and the line has gone. It was showing at the top of my terminal when I launched it.

Comment: So is it solved or is there still a problem?

Comment: It's solved as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

*Stumbled upon this while debugging an issue, just clarifying for future interweb travelers.*

Edit your `~/.zshrc` file and add this:

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Restart your terminal.

---

Here are some helpful links

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25452411/6114891

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42002830/6114891