# I have to type export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:"$PATH" everytime I rerun the terminal

Tags: shell, anaconda

I have installed the Anaconda for Mac, but there is something wrong with me:

when I type the command`which conda` or `which ipython`, I get `conda not found` and `ipython not find`

Then I find this command `export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:"$PATH"` works for me. It solves the problem above, but everytime I rerun the terminal the problem is still there,  I have to type it again.

so I want to find a way to solve the problem fundamentally

I have tried to add it into the `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, but these don't work for me.

Comment: did u try the source ~/.bashrc command?

Comment: See [How to make OS X to read .bash_profile not .profile file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18773051)

Comment: Use `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}+' bash -l -x` to get a trace of which of your dotfiles are run in what order. Look through that trace to see where PATH is being set and re-set.

Comment: ...wouldn't be surprised at all if your code is running correctly, but something is overwriting its changes later in execution; collecting the trace, as above, will show that.

Comment: BTW, I'd argue that this question is substantially mistagged. It has nothing to do with python, or ipython, or anaconda -- you'd have the exact same behavior adding any other directory to your PATH whether or not it related to this software, and subject-matter expertise on those subjects doesn't make it at all easier for someone to answer this question.

Comment: Indeed, I'd argue that it's not specific to development tools at all, and belongs on SuperUser rather than StackOverflow (since folks can need to change PATH for all manner of non-development-related reasons).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ok, thank you very much! I  will do better next time

Comment: @herokingsley yes, I have tried, but it have the same problem

Comment: ...btw, have you had a chance to run that trace? I'm curious as to whether it's illuminating.

Comment: @Hua.L, this is a case where an off-site pastebin-type facility (ideally without ads, such as https://gist.github.com/ or http://ix.io/) is probably appropriate, if the log is too long to edit into the question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ...ok, I am sorry.
 https://gist.github.com/AGrowingTree/03127a7284977c9849ba

Comment: @CharlesDuffy May I have your e-mail address？
this is mine:

waajoenglei@gmail.com

Comment: From that log, everything looks fine. Did you log out and back in (to activate changes to `~/.bash_profile`), or are you only activating a terminal window? I'd also suggest checking that your shell really is bash -- if you changed to zsh, fish, or similar, that would explain it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  yeh...the problem is that I use the zsh yesterday....
and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this in ***.bash_profile***

```
export PATH="$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Then try launching a new terminal and running:

```
echo $PATH
```

The output should start with **/anaconda/bin:**

If that still doesn't work... A work around might be to invoke bash after running terminal i.e. type "***bash***". Which should cause bash to launch with .bash_profile

Comment: I get  /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin    after call echo, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: add `export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH` to ~/.bash_profile, and open a new terminal, it works

Comment: For me, I had to add the line `export PATH="$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH"` to **_~/.bashrc_** instead. This was the only way to make it work.

Answer (score 9):

I run on MacOs Catalina 10.15 and this did the trick for me:
shell is zsh !

```
$ source /Users/myprofilename/anaconda3/bin/activate
```

then

```
$ conda init zsh
```

the new anaconda documentation also [highlights this](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/):

Comment: I suppose problem was due to zsh

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're not using ZShell or another form of a shell. If the case you'd have to add the path to your respective shell file, e.g `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo xed /etc/environment
```

after open this archive add :/home/youruser/anaconda3/bin

Answer (score 1):

### conda path fix

Best fix is to set your conda base to auto activate.

If you entered "no", when it asked whether you want to automatically initialize conda whenever you need to use it, it will not update your $SHELL variable by adding:

```
export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

in /home/user/.bashrc

Then do :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

check whether the path is exported by

```
echo $PATH
```

after this do :

```
conda init
```

For Permanent fix :

The base environment is activated by default

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base True
```

The base environment is not activated by default

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base False
```

## The above commands only work if conda init has been run first

I hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ZShell follow the steps below:

1. In your terminal type *open ~/.zshrc*
2. Add the following to the file *export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH*
3. Save your file and then run the following command *source ~/.zshrc*

**Please note that the homebrew path on Apple silicon is /opt/homebrew/bin**