# catkin build fails to compile

Tags: ros, catkin

I am trying to compile a build file for a sample tutorial in ROS packages. The following shows up in the Terminal,

```
Errors     << catkin_tools_prebuild:cmake /home/comet/mybot_ws/logs/catkin_tools_prebuild/build.cmake.009.log
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/home/comet/anaconda3/bin/python
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/comet/mybot_ws/build/catkin_tools_prebuild/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code No such file or directory
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:74 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:151 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
```

It appears that it is trying to access the python compiler in an anaconda3 folder but I have it uninstalled recently. Any ideas how I could modify the files so that it points to  /usr/bin python ? Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just resolved it recently, I have executed `catkin clean` before `catkin build`.

Comment: If the problem is solved by one of the answers, please accept it (by clicking the check mark left of the text), so that this question is marked as solved.

Comment: @D.0417 You need to install that package's dependencies with: `rosdep install <pkg-name>` or install with `apt-get`. undefined packages is in CMakeList line 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are two possibilities that your environment is tainted

1. Your `PATH` variable is still tainted by pointing to your anaconda location. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076536/i-have-to-type-export-path-anaconda-binpath-everytime-i-rerun-the-terminal) for reference and remove the anaconda entry. Don't forget to open a new terminal to apply the changes
2. You've created the local catkin workspace while you've sourced the anaconda environment. Thus, you just need to delete `build` and `devel` in your current workspace and just rebuild everything from scratch.

Processing both steps one after another should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just resolved it recently, I have executed `catkin clean` before `catkin build`.

Comment: I don't understand why this got downvoted. Running `catkin clean` (which is equivalent to removing "build" and "devel" directories) should always be one of the first things to try when there is something weird with catkin build. This is definitely a legit and good answer.