# Installing Ruby 'rbenv: shell integration not enabled...' - have homebrew installed on macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Tags: ruby, bash, macos

I'm no developer or even remotely close, sorry please excuse my ignorance. I'm just trying to do a few things to improve my knowledge and communication with the Dev team.  I'm trying to install Ruby for use with our system.  I installed the most recent version of Homebrew and installed Ruby 2.5.1 (I think).

In the terminal I see:

```
rbenv shell 2.5.1
rbenv: shell integration not enabled. Run `rbenv init' for instructions.
rbenv init
# Load rbenv automatically by appending
# the following to ~/.bash_profile:
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

I have tried several things mentioned on various web boards, no luck.

I open the `.bash_profile` and `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` is the 1st entry.

Is this a problem? If yes, can I proceed?

Comment: Have you sourced the bash file, or opened a new terminal, or topped it in your current command line?

Comment: Hi David, I have closed and started a new terminal session.  I'm not sure what 'source' the bash file or topped it means.  I'll I see when I open the bash filed is eval "$(rbenv init -)" --i have checked for any spaces/hidden characters.

Answer (score 1):

What you will find is that on some systems `.bash_profile` just does not get used or executed.

Add `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to you `.bashrc` and then run

```
source .bashrc
```

Comment: Do you know on what systems it behaves like that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791486/differences-uses-and-similarities-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-etc-profil

Answer (score 0):

I am new and had this same issue.

I ended up running `echo 'eval $rebenv init -' >> ~/.bashrc`

Then `source ~/.bashrc`