# How to restart the shell inside the bash script and continue the execution of the script?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nix

**The initial problem:** Install the nix package manager then install other programs (e. g. lua) using the nix by launching a bash script only once.

**The solution:** I have written the following bash script *install.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash

install_nix() (
        echo "installing nix..."
        echo ""

        curl --location https://releases.nixos.org/nix/nix-2.18.1/install | sh -s -- --daemon

        echo ""
)

if ! command -v nix-env &> /dev/null; then
        echo "nix is not installed"

        install_nix
fi

nix-env --install --attr nixpkgs.lua
```

**The problem:** the script results in the following:

```
./install.sh: line 18: nix-env: command not found
```

because the nix package manager requires the shell restart after installation

> ---- Reminders -----------------------------------------------------------------
>
> [ 1 ]
>
> Nix won't work in active shell sessions until you restart them.

**So what do I want:** *somehow restart the shell inside the script and continue the execution from there so I do not need to restart the shell and launch the script one more time manually*

**What have I tried to solve the problem:**

1 **exec bash**

```
...
if ! command -v nix-env &> /dev/null; then
        echo "nix is not installed"

        install_nix

        exec bash
fi
...
```

2 **exec $0 $@**

```
...
if ! command -v nix-env &> /dev/null; then
        echo "nix is not installed"

        install_nix

        exec @0 $@
fi
...
```

3 **exec bash "$0" "$@"**

```
...
if ! command -v nix-env &> /dev/null; then
        echo "nix is not installed"

        install_nix

        exec bash @0 $@
fi
...
```

4 **subshell**

```
...
if ! command -v nix-env &> /dev/null; then
        echo "nix is not installed"

        ( install_nix )
fi
...
```

5 **command substitution $()**

```
...
if ! command -v nix-env &> /dev/null; then
        echo "nix is not installed"

        $(install_nix)
fi
...
```

6 **command substitution ``**

```
...
if ! command -v nix-env &> /dev/null; then
        echo "nix is not installed"

        `install_nix`
fi
...
```

7 **just bash**

```
...
if ! command -v nix-env &> /dev/null; then
        echo "nix is not installed"

        bash install_nix
fi
...
```

8 bash + source

```
...
if ! command -v nix-env &> /dev/null; then
        echo "nix is not installed"

        new_shell = $(bash)
        source install_nix
        disown $new_shell
fi
...
```

> **It is all happening inside WSL Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS**

**So the question is:** how to *somehow restart the shell inside the script and continue the execution from there so it does not require restarting the shell and launching the script one more time manually?*

Comment: you can source the bashrc or I believe reset command also resets the terminal.

Comment: I have tried both: source ~/.bashrc and reset command - it haven't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source /etc/profile && nix-env --install --attr nixpkgs.lua`

Comment: or `/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin/nix-env --install --attr nixpkgs.lua`

Comment: wow, that's work! thank you! can you please explain how it works?

Comment: maybe you need this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791486/differences-uses-and-similarities-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-etc-profil

Answer (score 1):

You can restart the script, not `bash`

```
exec "$0" "$@"
```

and inside your script detect different conditions (i.e. `nix` already installed).

Comment: It's the 3 way I have tried to solve the problem as I described in question body. But I have tried this way one more time now. It is result in infinite recursive - probably because `command -v nix-env &> /dev/null` returns non-zero exit code even in restarted script.