# How do I add a command to .profile?

Tags: bash

I would like the command

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=echo
```

to be executed every time I open bash. I've been told that this command can be read from `~/.profile`, however, I do not know how to put it there.

Comment: Add the command to .bash_profile

Comment: Open the file and add the command. The file is .bash_profile (runs at login) or .bashrc (for each time you open a terminal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo 'PROMPT_COMMAND=echo' >> ~/.profile`

Comment: Ah, I did not realise it was as simple as using `>>`!

Answer (score 1):

If you are on mac, you have to add it to

```
~/.bash_profile
```

If on linux, it'll go in

```
~/.bashrc
```

Comment: That's not quite right. .bash_profile and .bashrc are both linux. .profile is mac. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment  more info: http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html

Comment: Bash uses the same files on every OS, and uses both of these files for different purposes.

Comment: More specifically, the Mac `Terminal` application starts a login shell by default, while most Linux-based terminal emulators start a non-login shell by default, hence the difference.