# XCode doesn't recognize `pod keys`

Tags: ios, xcode, rubygems, cocoapods, twitter-fabric

Here's my setup

Env:

- Mac 10.11.6
- Gem 2.4.8

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'cocoapods', '~> 1.1.1'
gem 'cocoapods-keys', '~> 1.7.0'
gem 'fastlane'
```

Installed [Cocoapods-keys](https://github.com/orta/cocoapods-keys) using:

```
gem install cocoapods-keys
```

Added Fabric Run Script:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/iOS/Fabric.framework/run" `pod keys get FabricAPIKey` `pod keys get FabricAPISecret`
```

**Errors:**

```
[33mWARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
[0m
~/Development/Projects/ABC/raven/Pods/Fabric/iOS/Fabric.framework/run: eval: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `('
~/Development/Projects/ABC/raven/Pods/Fabric/iOS/Fabric.framework/run: eval: line 18: `"~/Development/Projects/ABC/raven/Pods/Fabric/iOS/Fabric.framework/uploadDSYM" [!] Unknown command: `keys` Did you mean: repo Usage: $ pod COMMAND CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager. Commands: + cache Manipulate the CocoaPods cache + init Generate a Podfile for the current directory. + install Install project dependencies to Podfile.lock versions + ipc Inter-process communication + lib Develop pods + list List pods + outdated Show outdated project dependencies + plugins Show available CocoaPods plugins + repo Manage spec-repositories + search Search for pods. + setup Setup the CocoaPods environment + spec Manage pod specs + trunk Interact with the CocoaPods API (e.g. publishing new specs) + try Try a Pod! + update Update outdated project dependencies and create new Podfile.lock Options: --silent Show nothing --version Show the version of the tool --verbose Show more debugging information --no-ansi Show output without ANSI codes --help Show help banner of specified command [!] Unknown command: `keys` Did you mean: repo Usage: $ pod COMMAND CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager. Commands: + cache Manipulate the CocoaPods cache + init Generate a Podfile for the current directory. + install Install project dependencies to Podfile.lock versions + ipc Inter-process communication + lib Develop pods + list List pods + outdated Show outdated project dependencies + plugins Show available CocoaPods plugins + repo Manage spec-repositories + search Search for pods. + setup Setup the CocoaPods environment + spec Manage pod specs + trunk Interact with the CocoaPods API (e.g. publishing new specs) + try Try a Pod! + update Update outdated project dependencies and create new Podfile.lock Options: --silent Show nothing --version Show the version of the tool --verbose Show more debugging information --no-ansi Show output without ANSI codes --help Show help banner of specified command validate run-script'
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

**Fixes that I've tried that didn't work:**

- added `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` to ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile
- export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036036/setting-up-xcode-for-cocoapods-plugin/20534156#20534156)
- fix permission using [this](https://github.com/orta/cocoapods-keys/issues/139#issuecomment-223714315)
- deleted /Pods, Pod.lock and ran `bundle install` and `bundle exec pod install`

**Things that works:**

- On Terminal, run `pod keys`

So apparently `pod keys` runs well on my mac, but XCode doesn't recognise it, any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `bundle exec pod install` inside the script?

Comment: yes I ran that prior to XCode build. I also tried "${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/iOS/Fabric.framework/run" `bundle exec pod keys get FabricAPIKey` `bundle exec pod keys get FabricAPISecret`

Comment: Here's my [github issue](https://github.com/orta/cocoapods-keys/issues/159#issuecomment-272219033). Appreciate it if you can check it out!