# Updated Git but still showing old version

Tags: macos, git, terminal, updates

I downloaded and installed Git 1.8.4.2 from this link: http://git-scm.com/downloads.  However, when I run `git --version` from the Terminal I get:

```
[~/workspace/ruby]:  git --version 
git version 1.7.4.4
```

I've tried restarting the terminal and my computer.  I then tried using the info at https://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/wiki/Uninstall.  I did the following in the terminal from within /usr:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/git
sudo rm /etc/paths.d/git
sudo rm /etc/manpaths.d/git
```

I then ran the new git .dmg file again but am still getting 1.7.4.4 when I run `git --version`.  I suppose there's something going on here with the Mac filesystem that I don't understand.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Most likely it's not a programming, but a question about mac osx usage

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Run the command:

```
which git
```

You'll probably see `/usr/bin/git` -- the Apple supplied version. This will be because `/usr/bin` appears in your `PATH` environment variable *before* `/usr/local/git/bin`. You can verify this by running the command:

```
echo $PATH
```

If that is the case then run this command:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

and then try `git --version` again. You should now get `1.8.4.2`. This hasn't fixed it permanently yet though. You'll need to add the `export PATH=...` line to your `~/.bashrc` so that it gets set for every shell.

Comment: Thank you!  Worked like a charm.  I was able to see it had something to do with $PATH from other questions here but I couldn't find the right line to add to my ~/.bashrc (I ran open ~/.bash_profile which is the same thing, right?).  THanks again!

Comment: @sixty4bit See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment) for an explanation of the difference between `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`.