# Set umask for remote commands

Tags: capistrano

How can I direct processes started on remote machines via ssh to run with a certain umask?  I want this to apply to commands run as part of standard Capistrano recipes too, so I can't just make an explicit call to "umask" part of the command.

It does not appear that ~/.bash_profile on the remote machine is read, with the way that Capistrano invokes remote commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was confronted to the same issue and got around it by using the then-undocumented `SSHKit.config.umask` in `config/deploy.rb`. Note that this will set the `umask` for every ssh command.

Comment: Just a note to say this doesn't work if you use the `execute('some command')` syntax, you have to use `execute(:some, 'command')` so that it is in interpreted via the [command map](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit#the-command-map)

Comment: This works only for Capistrano 3. Capistrano 2 doesn't use SSHKit.

Answer (score 2):

Put **umask 0002** in the **.bashrc** of the user account you use to deploy.

Comment: This works. i had my umash in my deploy user's .bash_profile file but realized for a passwordless ssh user this profile file seems to be not used and .bashrc does

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Alain--set the umask in your `.bashrc` instead of `.bash_profile`.  When deploying with Capistrano in a typical setup, your `.bash_profile` isn't loaded by default.  Reading up on [the difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment) will help in understanding the purposes of the two.
I have environment variables set in my `.bashrc` file and they are certainly used when I deploy or for running any other commands with capistrano.

Another option is to create a task to set your umask value before you begin creating files on deploy.  For example, in Cap 3, you can use this:

```ruby
task :set_umask do
  on roles(:all) do |host|
    execute "umask 0002"
  end
end
before "deploy:starting", "set_umask"
```

Comment: Your capistrano-based solution does not seem to work. However, setting SSHKit.config.umask = "0002" in config/deploy.rb does the trick.

Comment: @beauby oh god and this is not documented **anywhere**. Care to make this an answer?

Comment: @FelixFrank: Yeah, I remember having a hard time finding it... Done!

Answer (score 0):

@beauby's answer using SSHKit is good, but it works only for Capistrano 3 as Capistrano 2 doesn't use SSHKit.

A common problem in relation to `umask` and Capistrano is that `bundle install` installs gems with permissions that are too restrictive. For this specific issue, the solution I've found for Capistrano 2 is to say:

```rb
namespace :bundle do
  task :postinstall do
    run "chmod -R u=rwX,go=rX #{bundle_dir}"
  end
end

after 'bundle:install', 'bundle:postinstall'
```