# what are the differences between the various ways to instantiate JAVA_HOME in ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, java-home

There are various ways to set the `JAVA_HOME` variable in ubuntu , simply write the following lines:

```
JAVA_HOME = / usr/lib/jvm/java-...... 

export JAVA_HOME
```

etc ...

but what's the DIFFERENCE if these commands are added:

1] in `/etc/profile.d/java.sh` 
2] in `.Profile`

Or another way.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to change the variable in your terminal windows, set it in `.bashrc` file, which is sourced each time a new terminal is opened. `.profile` file is not sourced each time you open a new terminal.

See the difference between .profile and .bashrc in question: [What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)

Comment: I have a related question here. Please help me to fix the problem -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931383/error-java-home-is-not-defined-correctly-despite-setting-it

Answer (score 0):

The first option will apply to all users.

The second (I suppose you mean `$HOME/.profile`) applies only to you.

Note that system wide, if you have several JDKs installed with your package manager, you may want to use the `update-alternatives` command.

Note however that `.profile` only applies to login shells; you had better put these lines into `.bashrc` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The first method keeps JAVA_HOME environment variable active only till the time the terminal session is active. If you close the terminal type $JAVA_HOME again it will fail.

The second option adds it to the profile of the user making it like a permanent environment variable which will persist even after a restart.

Answer (score 0):

Let say that, you want to add an environment variable on current terminal like `JAVA_HOME`, or `HTTP_PROXY` you can directly set it with `export` command. When you close terminal, that assignment will be lost. Simply, it is instant assignment for that running operation.

In second option, if you define an entry to `.bashrc`, it will be available to logged in user that has `.bashrc`. If you want to set permanent variables for specific user, you can define it in `.bashrc` in user's home folder.

Additionally, if you put `export` commant in `/etc/environment`, it will be available to all users

Comment: I have a related question here. Please help me to fix the problem -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931383/error-java-home-is-not-defined-correctly-despite-setting-it