# Can I export PATH twice in .bashrc?

Tags: bash, heroku-toolbelt, aws-cli

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and trying to be ale to use both the Heroku CLI as well as the newly-downloaded AWS Elastic Beanstalk CLI tools.

I have this code in my .bashrc already:

```
### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
```

And I also want to export this:

```
#for Elastic Beanstalk - madebyian
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.0/eb/linux/python3/
```

How do I get both CLI tools and/or what's wrong with my syntax EDIT:[if anything]?

Comment: FYI, `.bashrc` isn't generally the right place to update your PATH -- you'll get entries added multiple times as shells started by other shells invoke it after it's already been run by a parent. Environment updates generally belong in `.bash_profile`, so they're run only once per login.

Comment: Anyhow, "what's wrong?" assumes that *anything's* wrong. Show us the `PATH` you're getting, so we can tell why you think anything is wrong.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can export it as many times as you want, it will make no difference (after the first export, obviously).

All `export` does in this context (other than changing the variable itself due to the `=`) is mark a variable so that it's exported to the environment of future commands.

You can *mark* it so as much as you want. The effect of the two commands:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.0/eb/linux/python3/
```

will be to mark `PATH` as an export variable (it probably is so already since you generally *want* your path to be inherited) and set it to:

```
/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH:/opt/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.0/eb/linux/python3/
```

where `$PATH` was the path *before* executing those commands.

The only thing you need to be careful of is the ordering. For example, if `/usr/local/heroku/bin` contains an executable program called `ls`, that's probably going to make life difficult for you if you're trying to get a directory listing. For that reason, I tend to add directories only to the *end* of the path.

Alternatively, you can make the order less permanent by providing an alias or function which changes your path to the Heroku-preferred one only for the current session.

---

Keep in mind that the files that get run by `bash` are a [complex matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment#answer-415444). `.bashrc` is run for interactive, non-login shells so may not run in all cases (I, for one, fix that by calling `.bashrc` at the end of my `.bash_profile` though some people may cringe at that).

You're probably better off setting (and exporting) the path in your `.bash_profile`.

---

And, if there is something wrong with what you're doing (your *syntax* seems fine but there may be other problems we cannot discern due to lack of information), you should perform the following steps:

- `echo $PATH` before and after each `export` command to see if something is stuffing it up.
- ensure that each component in the path actually *exists* (i.e., that you have the correct directories in there).

Comment: Maybe it will be usefull to make a ref to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment#answer-415444

Comment: +1; > "exported to the environment of future commands" - more accurately, exported to the environment of any future _child processes of the current (shell) process_. This implies that preexisting shell instances and their (potentially future) child processes are NOT affected. Thus, as @CharlesDuffy points out, `~/.bash_profile` is the best place to put `export` commands.