# Cannot use alias while executing a command via SSH

Tags: bash, ssh

I commented out this line in .bashrc:

```
# [ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

and now the alias gets read, but I still cannot execute it... :/

We can ask the server if the alias has been defined:

```
$ ssh server "cd /tmp && alias backup_tb"
alias backup_tb='pg_dump -U david tb > tb.sql'
```

But it is not expanded:

```
$ ssh server "cd /tmp && backup_tb"
bash: backup_tb: command not found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Note these are different things. The alias in `.bashrc` apply for the server where this file is stored, while you are trying to use them in a `ssh` command, so in another server.

Comment: @fedorqui He actually defined the alias in the remote `.bashrc`  The first ssh command *shows* that the definition exists.  The second shows that it isn't honoured.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld you are totally right, didn't pay enough attention.

Comment: I edited this for clarity and split the two ssh sections.

Comment: I am thinking that it might have to do with `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. [What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)

Comment: tried to symlink .bash_profile to .bashrc ... this helped in some other case... but not here

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quoted from the man page of `bash`: *Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt ...*

So the simplest way IMO is to put the following lines at the top of your `/home/<user>/.bashrc` file:

```
# comment out the original line
# [ -z "$PS1" ] && return

if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
  shopt -s expand_aliases
  # alias ls='ls --color=always'
  # return
fi
```

Save and exit. Now you can run `ssh user@host "your_alias"` successfully.

Comment: ah yes! I was testing this one before but I haven't commented out the line `"[ -z "$PS1" ] && return"` yet then... So it didn't work because  .bash_aliases didn't get loaded. So the solution is to do *both* of these things. Thank you!

Comment: I would rephrase or drop that last sentence about `ssh user@host "alias"`.  The question already showed that the `alias` command works with our without the `shopt -s ...`.

Answer (score -1):

```
# WARNING!!!! Just effective in openssh-server.!!!!!!!

# cd your loacl user .ssh path 
# if you want to make all user has the same alias you should go to 
#'/etc/ssh' touch a file 'sshrc'
# what is 'sshrc'? he has the same function as 'rc.local',just a shell 
# script when you first login.  

# The following is a configuration of the current user .
cd ~/.ssh

touch sshrc  

chmod +x sshrc

#edit sshrc and type 

alias ll="ls -lah --color"

#Apply changes

source sshrc
```

Comment: explain it please

Comment: sshrc like bashrc it will be run when login in

Comment: Forget to say that only openssh effective.

Comment: Explain it **in the answer itself** please. Note that [comments are temporary and could be deleted anytime](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have additional information to provide, please update your answer by clicking on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/204869) for details. Thank you.