# Problems running Mahout and Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mahout, java-home, mahout-recommender

I'm new at `Mahout` and `Hadoop`.

I've successfully installed `Hadoop Cluster` with 3 machines, and the cluster is running fine, and I just installed `Mahout` on the Main namenode for "testing purposes", and I followed the instructions of installation and set the `JAVA_HOME`, but when I try to run `classify-20newsgroups.sh` it goes and download the `dataset` but after that I get the following error:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not set
```

Then I've revised the `.bashrc` and confirmed that the `JAVA_HOME` is set correctly, but it doesn't help.

Also how do I verify that `Mahout` is configured to run on `Hadoop` correctly and do you know of any example that can verify this configuration or environment?

Answer (score 0):

The .bashrc is only read by a shell that is **non-login**, otherwise is read .bash_profile. 
So you could set to read .bashrc from .bash_profile (see here [What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)) or just a set JAVA_HOME in **.bash_profile**.

There are another several possibilities to set the JAVA_HOME:

1) set .bashrc from terminal

```
~$ source .bashrc
```

2) set JAVA_HOME in open terminal before running *classify-20newsgroups.sh*

```
~$ JAVA_HOME=/path
~$ classify-20newsgroups.sh
```

3) run classify-20newsgroups.sh with JAVA_HOME, i.e.

```
~$ JAVA_HOME=/path classify-20newsgroups.sh
```

---

As for question about Mahout configuration for run on Hadoop. Standart example with classify-20newsgroups should work on hadoop if HADOOP_HOME is set.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to explicitly set JAVA_HOME in hadoop-env.sh

In hadoop-env.sh, look for the comment "#The java implementation to use", and modify the JAVA_HOME path under it.

It should look something like this:

> # The java implementation to use.
>
> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

Of course fix the path of JAVA_HOME.