# Change CDPATH permanently

Tags: bash, environment-variables, permanent

I am using Linux Mint 16 with xfce and I have the following problem:

For my work I always have to switch to a long path in my File system.
I tried to avoid this by adding this one particular folder to my CDPATH.
I added the path with:

```
export CDPATH=$CDPATH:/directory/to/add
```

But this only works for one terminal session. After closing the terminal, the CDPATH is gone again.
I have read to put the given line for exporting into my .bashrc or my .profile or some other files, but none of them worked permanently.

So, how can I add a directory to my CDPATH permanently ?
Maybe with a bash Script in my autostart ?

Comment: put it in `~/.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add it in `~/.bash_profile`, if you want to use it in a non-login session then add it in `~/.bashrc`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment) is a explanation for the difference between them.

Comment: Thank you. I do not know, why this did not work the first time, but now anything works. I will close accept and close this as soon as I can.

Comment: You can run `source ~/.bash_profile` to make this take effect in sessions opened before you add the configuration.