# How to call a command without giving its full path?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terminal, command

I installed a text editor under `/usr/share/my-editor/editor-executable`.

When I want to launch the editor in terminal I have to write the complete path:

```
# /usr/share/my-editor/editor-executable file-to-open
```

I would create a command for the editor so I can simply digit:

```
# my-editor file-to-open
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you couldn't launch your executable is because the shell look for the command in any of the paths defined in the `PATH` environment variable (*known paths* from now).
You can check those *known paths* with:

```
echo $PATH
```

As you can see, `/usr/bin` is defined there as well as other paths.

Anyway, you can get what you want in several ways.

---

*Note below that when I use the **~** directory, the command will be only available for the current user.*

#### Creating an alias `my-editor`

This is my favourite when you want to run a command which is not found in the *known paths*. It would be a good idea for you too. In `bash` you can place the alias in `~/.bash_aliases`.

```
echo alias my-editor=/usr/share/my-editor/my-editor-executable >> ~/.bash_aliases
```

---

#### Creating a link to your file in some of the *known paths*

*It's the way you have done it* and just to clarify, if you had created the link in any of the *known paths*, it would have worked too.

```
ln -s /usr/share/my-editor/my-editor-executable /usr/bin/my-editor
```

---

#### Defining a function with name `my-editor`

I think it's too much due to your needs but it's up to you if want to give it a try. It can be useful for other purposes.
You must define it in a file read by your shell. e.g. `~/.bashrc` in `bash`. [Shell files invocation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)

```
cat >> ~/.bashrc << "EOF"
function my-editor() {
    /usr/share/my-editor/my-editor-executable "$@"
}
EOF
```

---

#### Adding `/usr/share/my-editor/` to the `PATH`

You can add a new path to the `PATH` variable. In Ubuntu, the `PATH` variable is generally set in `/etc/environment` and if you modify this file, the new path will be accesible for all users.

However, if you want to be the only one who has access to the new path, you can set it in one of the *personal* shell files. e.g. in `bash`: `~/.bashrc`. [Shell files invocation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/share/my-editor/"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

---

#### [`bash`] Entering a command into the *hash table*

A singular way to get the same result in `bash` is adding `my-editor` into the shell [`hash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-hash) table. Again, you must add the command in some file read by `bash` (`~/.bashrc`).

```
echo 'hash -p /usr/share/my-editor/my-editor-executable my-editor' >> ~/.bashrc
```

---

#### Moving the executable to a *known path*

Finally, if you don't need the file (`my-editor-executable`) in his current directory anymore, you can simply move it to a *known path*.

```
mv /usr/share/my-editor/my-editor-executable /usr/bin/my-editor
```

Comment: Very complete answer!!

Answer (score 0):

I answer by myself:

I created a link to executable file under /usr/bin :

```
# ln -sF /usr/share/my-editor/my-editor-executable   /usr/bin/my-editor
```

Now it is possible to run the application "my-editor" via terminal everywhere in the file system