# bashrc does not run automatically in OS X

Tags: bash

I set environment variables in bashrc but every time I should run:

> source ~/.bashrc

and then it works! Also same for .profile file!

Comment: In OSX you might want to use `.bash_profile`. Difference between those files is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/415403/2890168

Answer (score 0):

I just coppied the contents of my .bashrc to .bash_profile and that's it.