# Trying to make a permanent Alias - UNIX

Tags: linux, bash, unix, alias

I am trying to make a permanent alias (`alias homedir='cd /export/home/Files/myName'`) in unix.

I am trying to add the command in the ~/.bashrc file, but I cannot find the file in my $HOME directory. The only bash file is see is .bash_history, Please help.

I even did a `ls -a` and still did not find it in my $HOME directory.

Comment: Just create the file.

Comment: ok - thanks for that - will do - is there any structure? or just do $vi .bashrc?

Comment: you can just do `vi .bashrc` like you said

Comment: thanks - i added the following line to the file (alias homedir='cd /export/home/Files/myName') ; but when i do homedir it says command not found

Comment: i restarted the session also but still nothing

Comment: Seemingly obvious question: Are you using bash as your shell?

Comment: yes , right now I am using bash i think ; i get the error -bash: homedir: command not found

Comment: You're using bash as a login shell.  You need to edit `~/.profile` instead.

Comment: you mean the .profile in my home directory? and just put the alias there? (alias homedir='cd /export/home/Files/myName' )

Comment: Yes.  Login shells source that instead of `.bashrc` or its equivalents.  It's somewhat common to point one at the other with the `source` builtin so you don't need to edit both.

Comment: I just added it to .profile and that worked ! thanks!!

Comment: Don't forget to consult the Bash manual on [Startup Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files).

Comment: Is `/export/home/Files/myName` actually your home directory (`$HOME`)? If so, the alias is not necessary; `cd` with no arguments changes to your home directory. If not, perhaps `homedir` is not the best name for your alias.

Comment: You're welcome -- but you didn't answer my question.

Comment: Sorry Keith - you are correct - the path you mentioned is actually my home directory ($HOME). I don't need an alias for that path as I can just specify $HOME itself. I just used that path as an example.... I will be using that alias for other paths

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise against placing your aliases directly in ~/.profile (which was suggested in the comments).  The ~/.profile file is not specific to bash.

You should instead place your aliases in ~/.bashrc.

### Why?

1. .bashrc is guaranteed to be specific to bash (or at least any future variant of it)
2. If you set everything up correctly, all of your shells can follow a similar convention.  So you can have .bashrc, .zshrc, .tcshrc, .kshrc, etc.

   - If you're like me and enjoy playing around with all the different shells, you will find this very *very* helpful

### How to Set It Up

Place the following code in ~/.profile.

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

This will ensure that ~/.bashrc runs if and only if you're using bash.
So ultimately, ~/.profile *is* involved; but you still benefit from having all your aliases (and any other bash-specific commands) in a bash-specific file.  The reason you need to add this to .profile is explained here: [What's The difference between the different scripts for bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/415403/2065237).

Then add your aliases and other commands to ~/.bashrc.  If ~/.bashrc does not already exist, just create it either with `touch ~/.bashrc` or `vi ~/.bashrc`.

Remember to re-apply ~/.bashrc whenever you modify it.  Otherwise, you won't see the changes.  To do that, run this code:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I did place the alias in the .bashrc file. I then relogged into Unix and ran the alias - nothing happened. So that's why I put the Alias in the profile.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I added the alias to ~/.profile and restarted the session. It worked.

Comment: @peterh Actually, this post does answer the original question.  It was just worded in such a way that it didn't sound like it.  Also, note that the answerer here is the OP.  I have updated the wording of the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: It's ok sildoreth - your answer is more brief - I won't me marking mine as the correct answer even though you could do it that way .. I'll mark yours

Comment: Did you mean you were going to mark my answer as the accepted answer?  It looks like you forgot to do this.