# Ionic cordova build

Tags: linux, cordova, build, sdk, ionic-framework

I have issues with cordova and ionic.
When I start a project only with Cordova
I can build and emulate Android.

```
$ cordova build android && cordova emulate android
```

But, if I create a Ionic project. When I try build and emulate the console show me this message:

```
Running command: /home/juanobrach/moonpicker/Ionic/test1/platforms/android/cordova/build 
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/juanobrach/moonpicker/Ionic/test1/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /home/juanobrach/moonpicker/Ionic/test1/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

I'm really so confused about it

Comment: Is the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable set for your user? While I don't know why plain Cordova can detect it and Ionic can't, this is the core of the error.

Comment: Me too. I don't know why...

The ANDROID_HOME is correctly configure. I know this becouse I can run "android" command in my bash.
And when I write ANDROID_HOME the console write me the path of my Android sdk folder.

Maybe this is a bug for Ionic. Not for my environment.

Answer (score 0):

you need set the enviromental variables

in ubuntu try this
this directory is where are your android sdk

```
export ANDROID_HOME=PATH_ANDROID_SDK

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

Comment: OK, thanks Guardezi. I did that . But I'm not sure what is the default bash config file .
I have : .bashprofile ; .bashrc ; .profile.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment

Answer (score 0):

You should add it to your `.bashrc` file located in `/home/juanobrach` then restart your computer or run

```
source /home/juanobrach/.bashrc

export ANDROID_HOME=PATH/ANDROID_SDK

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```