# Execute a shell file from anywhere

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I can open my Arduino and Android Studio IDE irrespective of my current path by these commands

```
 ~/arduino/./arduino 
 ~/android/./studio
```

I've created aliases for both of them on my `.bashrc` file and its working fine.

I want to know if there is a more efficient way of solving this kind of problems?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "more efficient way"?

Comment: The way you do it is completely fine. I guess you have `alias myopen=vi ~/arduino...`?

Comment: try `export PATH="/bin:/sbin:/home/USERNAME/arduino:$PATH"`

then

`source ~/.bashrc`

now you will be able to execute your script from anywhere

don't forget to `chmod 770 yourscript`

Answer (score 0):

`~` represents you home directory in your system. That is why you can open those programs from anywhere. **But, if you login as another user, this won't work as `~` would then represent to that user's home directory.**

If you want you can replace `~` by `/home/<yourUsername>` (the absolute path to your home directory) or even `/root` depending upon your installation settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can add folders to your users path variable in the .profile file in your home directory. (or .bash_profile if it exists, since bash will prefer that folder.)

See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your `PATH` variable in your `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/arduino"
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment) for an explanation of the differences between various Shell startup files.

Answer (score 0):

the answer given by ceving is good but incomplete, once added to your path, you can execute your file but you should not use the

```
./
```

extension. So finally you'll have to do:

```
 export PATH="/home/arduino:$PATH"
```

then just call your executable file:

```
 arduino
```

```
 studio
```