# How to config the emacs shell prompt in OSX

Tags: macos, emacs

I want the shell of emacs show the absolute path. My system shell is config like following

```
export PS1='\u@MacAir:\w$ '
```

I have try [this way](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ShellMode). It can't work for me .

**PS**: My emacs is emacs24

**Solution** : Add `export PS1='\u@MacAir:\w$ '`  into `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Which shell in Emacs do you mean exactly?

Comment: The shell is generated by `M+x shell`

Comment: Which startup file did you put the export command in?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell prompt is not the responsibility of Emacs but of the shell you're running. Assuming you're using `bash`, check out the following question+answer:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/388913/how-to-make-ps1-display-full-path-name

which recommends the use of the special escape sequence `$PWD`:

```
export PS1='\u@MacAir:$PWD$ '
```

Put the above line in your `~/.bashrc` file for it to take effect in Emacs (as well as in normal terminals).

(A lot) more information can be found here: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/

Comment: That only work for system's shell, Not the the shell of emacs

Comment: Both shells are the same (bash). I've just tried out the following and it works without flaws: (1) Start Emacs; (2) type `M-x shell`; (3) in the shell, write `export PS1='\u@MacAir:$PWD$ '`. This gives the expected results.

Comment: Yes. But where should I set the `export PS1='\u@MacAir:$PWD$ '`. I don't want to write that command everytime when I open a shell in emacs

Comment: @Samuel -- Oh, sorry: since the link you provided in your original question already contains that information, I didn't include it in my answer. You should put that line in your `.bashrc` file in your `$HOME` directory, i.e., put it in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Actually I had put that in my `/etc/bashrc`. But it only works for the system shell. It doesn't work when I call shell in emacs by `M+x shell`.