# Load .bash_profile for every terminal

Tags: bash, macos, unix

I set up some aliases in my **.bash_profile** on my Max OS X.
It works but when I'm opening a new tab I always have to load my **.bash_profile** file with this command:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

How can I make it work for every terminal I'm opening, even if I'm restarting my Mac or Linux computer?

Comment: Try sourcing it from your ~/.bashrc (you may need to create that file).

Comment: Add your stuff to `~/.profile`. Or add : `[[ -r ~/.bash_profile ]] && . ~/.bash_profile` in `~/.profile`.

Comment: @l3x If `~/.bash_profile` exists it is sourced before than `~/.profile` in default bash.

Comment: @l3x, what is the correct sequence of sourcing these init scripts? One may end up sourcing same files recursively...

Comment: If you can configure your terminal to start a login shell, that should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, this helped.

Comment: I encountered the same issue , as in @P.P s comment . I opened up the ~/.profile which was empty when opened an added  the line [[ -r ~/.bash_profile ]] && . ~/.bash_profile then  ran source ~/.profile in my terminal and started working fine.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The files executed at the start may be several, usually ~/.bashrc for interactive, non-login shells. The kind I assume you are using.

If so, create an `~/.bashrc` file and source `~/.bash_profile` in it:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
    . ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

This [web site has a lot of information](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/) about this.

Study [this image](http://www.solipsys.co.uk/new/BashInitialisationFiles.html), as it is a condensed guide

If you do need to find out exactly which file is being executed, take a look at [this web page](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/10/execution-sequence-for-bash_profile-bashrc-bash_login-profile-and-bash_logout/). It has a lot of specific tests to find out what file is setting what.

Specific for Mac-OS (which is an exception and loads ~/.bash_profile) do as is recomended in the site [linked in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9458644/2350426) AFTER you confirm that your bash is doing as explained there.

Comment: Import `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile`, not the other way around. A login shell is a special case of an interactive shell. If you are using `.profile` instead of `.bash_profile`, make a `.bash_profile` that simply imports `.profile`.

Comment: @chepner The user is asking for a way to load `~./bash_profile` instead of doing it manually. So, it could not be the other way around. The file `~./bash_profile` is not being loaded (acording to the user).

Answer (score 43):

If you are using **zsh**, you can add `source ~/.bash_profile` at the end of the .zshrc file located at the following path: `/Users/YOUR USER NAME/.zshrc`

After making this change, restart your Terminal or iTerm2 application.

> Please note that the .zshrc file is hidden. To make it visible, you can press *CMD + SHIFT + .* in Finder.
> Alternatively, you can open it in the default text editor using the following command in the terminal:

```
open ~/.zshrc
```

**Update**

You don't need to perform these steps manually. You can run the following command instead:

```bash
echo "source ~/.bash_profile" >> ~/.zshrc
```

<sub>* Dont forget to restart your terminal.</sub>

Comment: it works . by adding . ~/.bash_profile this to ~/.zshrc file

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a pretty old post, but this problem comes and goes quite oftenly and a lot of laborous solutions are offered. The fact is: being aware of a simple info would solve this pretty fast and easy:

LINUX/Unix OS will load the profile files on startup following the rules below (some distros may have other files names, mainly for user local profiles, but the main rule follows this):

1. Login Shell

First and foremost: `/etc/profile` is loaded (global settings);
Next: `˜/.bash_profile` (local user settings- other files may be found, like `˜/.profile`, depending on the distro. Check documentation).

So, if you are in a Login Shell environment, put all your crazy stuff inside `˜/.bash_profile` (or the file provided by your distro) and everything will be fine.

2. Non-login Shell

First and foremost: `/etc/bashrc` (some distros will load `bash.bashrc`);
The next file to be seeked and loaded is `˜/.bashrc`

And that's why so many people (just like me) got frustrated having to source their `˜/.bash_profile` every single time a Terminal was loaded. We were simply inserting info in the "wrong" file- regarding the kind of shell loaded (see above: login, non-login).

More details on variants of the files mentioned above and some info on login vs non-login shell can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).

Hope it helps \o/

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu system -
Do it from **Terminal > Preferences** > Profile > Command > click on checkbox of **Run command as a login shell**
and then reopen the Terminal

[image: Screenshot of terminal preferences]