# What should I do to load specific bash_profile everytime I open a new Terminal window?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, alias

I've created some aliases in a `bash_profile` (followed [this](https://jonsuh.com/blog/bash-command-line-shortcuts/)) but when I open a new `Terminal` i need to write `source ~/.bash_profile` to use them.

I'd like to use the aliases as soon as I opened new `Terminal` windows, what should I do?

Comment: The linked blog post has a section on how to make your aliases permanent ("Permanent Aliases"). Have you tried that?

Comment: There's also [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99688/how-to-persistently-define-aliases-in-terminal) on https://apple.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: maybe your system loads  ~/.bashrc by default so you can try to put your aliases there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load .bash\_profile for every terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352907/load-bash-profile-for-every-terminal)

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Josh Staiger gives a good summary in his blogpost [".bash_profile vs .bashrc"](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html), summarised below:

- **.bash_profile** is executed when a user logs in via the console
- **.bashrc** is executed whenever a logged in user opens a new terminal window

So if you'd like to use newly created aliases as soon as you open a new terminal window, the solution is to use **.bashrc** instead of **.bash_profile** for your aliases.

The blog post includes some more details about synchronising PATHs that you set in .bashrc for logged in and non logged in shells, that may or may not be relevant to your specific problem.

Comment: It depends on how your terminal emulator is configured. On macOS, for example, the default is usually to open a new login shell for each window, because the terminal emulator itself wasn't started from a login shell itself (at whatever remove).

Comment: Specifically, `.bash_profile` is executed for a login shell; `.bashrc` is executed for a nonlogin interactive shell.