# Unix bash alias not working after start screen

Tags: bash, unix, alias, gnu-screen

Hi I am having a problem with setting alias in mac after I start the `screen` command, I have alias for working with git, like

```
commit=git commit
```

they work as I expect when I start my terminal (iTerm2), but then sometimes I use `screen` to have simultaneous instances in remotes servers and virtual machines I work with.  After this the alias disappear(`command not found`).

Does anyone know why or how solve it?

Comment: Are you still running the same shell, e.g., is your shell `bash` both outside and inside screen?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean you have `alias commit='git commit'`? What file is that defined in?

Comment: The alias disappears after you end the screen session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your aliases are defined in `~/.bashrc` to ensure they get included in all logins. You can test this out: edit your `~/.bashrc` to include this line:

```
echo "bashrc"
```

And then edit your `~/.bash_profile` to include this line:

```
echo "bash_profile"
```

You'll see when you start `screen` that only "bashrc" is displayed.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment) for much more detail on the subject.

Comment: Yes you are right, only the bashrc is run when I start screen, thanks you!

Answer (score 4):

To make the alias work, you must use the `alias` command. For example, to create an alias in Bash you do:

```
$ alias commit="git commit"
```

This works temporarily ie.: in your current shell. In order to make it "stick", you must put it in your `~/.bashrc`. That will make it be sourced to all instances of Bash you'll invoke during your terminal session.

When you start screen, it starts a separate Bash too, so you'll be covered.

You write something about VMs. If you need this alias to work there, you must make `~/.bashrc` on these VMs to have the same aliases. But that's the other story. You should already know how to achieve what you want.

Comment: yes I know what you mean, I wanted to be quick, my alias are in .bash_profile, which has higher priority that .bashrc

Comment: The problems with ``.bash_profile`` and ``.bashrc`` I typically debug by putting ``echo I_AM_IN_BASH_RC`` printout and figuring out whether this ``echo`` gets executed when you start ``screen``. If you don't see it, your file is simply not sourced somehow.

Comment: Thanks, I thought both of them we're being loaded, but just .bashrc was, I put my alias there and it's working fine. Thank you.