# Have to ~/.bashrc every time for virtualenvwrapper to work, why?

Tags: python, terminal, virtualenvwrapper

For some reason, every time I type the virtualenvwrapper command `WORKON` in Pycharm I get a "command not found" error. This will recur until I type `source ~/.bashrc` for **every new terminal** session in Pycharm. Normal Terminal sessions behave as expected.

These are the contents of my ~/.bashrc file:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Is this the natural behavior, any way to **not** have to type this source command every time?

Comment: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment) will give you some of the differences between the different shells but one line in particular that might be important because youre using `pycharm` is this - **`bash` complicates this in that `.bashrc` is only read by a shell that's both interactive and non-login**

Answer (score 1):

See this [blog](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html) for a detailed explanation of the difference between `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`.

TL;DR, add the following to your `.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  source ~/.bashrc
fi
```