# Why my rails command works differently with system() than in terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

The command that I'm trying to run is `rails _3.2.13_ new App`

When I run it in command line it creates a Rails app with version 3.2.13, but when I run it with `system "rails _3.2.13_ new #{self.name} -T -B"` it creates a Rails app with the latest version of Rails not 3.2.13 version.

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of Ruby using `/bin/sh` to execute shell commands, whereas you are probably using `/bin/bash` in Terminal on a daily basis. The way each is loaded and the specific configurations present in each will alter the configuration.

If you run `which rails` from both calls to `system` and in your terminal you'll likely see different paths. Check `echo $PATH` and you'll likely see different results too.

To resolve the situation, you can check out [What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment) which will give you a much better understanding of what's going on, then adjust your shell configuration to accomodate.

Comment: I ran `echo $PATH` in both and got the same result

`/Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin:/Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin:/Users/xxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin:/Users/xxxxx/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: I just found that when running `gem list --local` in terminal the gems are different than with `system()`

Comment: @robzdc Sounds like you've got some different ENV vars then.