# Updates of python not showing on terminal

Tags: python

I upgraded Python with "brew" from Python 2.7.5 to Python 2.7.14. I am using macOS Mavericks 10.9. I added this to `.profile`:

`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH".`

I don't want to mess with the system python (2.7.5). How do I make use of upgraded Python?

Comment: The problem is not clear, you have upgraded python, and you have added the export statement. thats should be it.

Comment: what do you see when you run **python --version** in your terminal ?

Comment: @my code I saw python 2.7.5 alone on the terminal

Comment: you have  **.profile **  or  **.bashrc**  ?

Comment: I used .profile @ mycode with the export statement I quoted above but it is not updating to python 2.7.14 I wanted.

Comment: incude PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH
export PATH in your profile insted to that. did you try already ?

Comment: @mycode now I have this PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH export PATH in my .profile but the python at the terminal still gives python 2.7.5 and not 2.7.14.

Comment: check my answer and try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well , you have to update your **.profile** with the following export. Replace your the export with the following one.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

After you add your export to your `.profile` and save it, remember to do `source ~/.profile` from the terminal before trying to load your `python`.

Also, I also use macOS and all my `PATH` extensions are actually in a file called `.bash_profile` rather than `.profile` (which in my case is empty).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment) describes the differences between .bashrc, .profile, and .bash_profile quite well.

Comment: No problem. I hope it helped!