# Weird behavior in bash and .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash

I have added `echo thisIsMyBash` at the end of my `.bashrc` file. Now when I write create a new terminal with `ctrl+alt+t`, **thisIsMyBash** is written a the beginning. This is as expected.

Now when I type `/bin/bash` in my terminal **thisIsMyBash** is also displayed in my terminal.

But when I write `/bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"` in my terminal, nothing is written. Why?

Also when I actually write `/bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc" && exec /bin/bash -li` **thisIsMyBash** also is displayed. Why that?

Any idea?

Comment: Is there anything in your `.bashrc` file that causes it to exit early if it isn't an interactive shell?

Comment: Not really a programming question, but in any case I cannot reproduce this behavior. Perhaps you have some logic earlier in your bashrc that causes it to stop executing before the echo under certain conditions? In a clean shell with nothing but the echo in the bashrc, I get it every time, including when run via `bash -c source`.

Comment: @MarkReed the behavior was easy to reproduce for me. Just placed echo at the end end just got the same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash\_profile, and .environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the "-i" option of bash it will work as desired. This option make the shell interactive. Try this:

```
/bin/bash -i -c "source ~/.bashrc"
```

Take a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101620/how-to-load-bashrc-from-bash-c).

Comment: This implies that there is code in the bashrc testing for interactivity and behaving differently when it is found. That context was not present in the question.