# I've screwed up my bash config, and I'm not sure how

Tags: centos

at this point when I log into my CentOS machine, I get this:

```
groostav@mymachine:~$ ssh root@my.company.com
root@my.company.com's password:
Last login: Mon Aug 20 13:52:47 2018 from s12345.vs.shawcable.net
-bash: brew: command not found
-bash-4.2#
```

I've gotten to this state by very carelessly trying to get a nice git prompt --evidently I even managed to get some mac osx code on my bash configuration path somehow. I've also blown up my old prompt which was in the form `user@host:pwd #`, which I would prefer.

I've been `grep`ing around but I cant find where the problem configuration is. Both the `/etc/bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` files look fine (the former seems like a default, and the latter has a number of commented-out lines in it).

*Where is this `brew` command and how did it get there!?*

*How did my prompt get reverted from the usual form to this basic form?*

> for bonus points, anybody know a very simple git prompt configuration? I'm remoting into this machine from linux machines and WSL, so fancy colors and unicode are a bad idea.

Many thanks!

Comment: Please check some of the other init files too, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/416931/1899640) has a list.

Comment: You're likely to get a better answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Comment: thanks @thatotherguy, but all those files look fine too. Can you bump me onto superuser.com as per my close vote & as per @zzxyz?