# Not able to start sqldeveloper without sudo in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, oracle-sqldeveloper

I installed Oracle SQL Developer following an article online in my Virtual Box Ubuntu.

My Ubuntu has IBM ACE 11 Developer Edition installed. So when I type java -version at terminal (user), I got this:

```
java version "1.8.0_271"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 8.0.6.20 - pxa6480sr6fp20ifix-20210224_01(SR6 FP20+IJ30974))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.9, JRE 1.8.0 Linux amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20210223_466229 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 5b31a42
OMR      - 4eb8f5f
IBM      - b7e48f4)
JCL - 20201119_01 based on Oracle jdk8u271-b0
```

But in my root terminal , my java -version is

```
java version "1.8.0_291"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b10, mixed mode)
```

JAVA_HOME in both .bashrc and /etc/profile are set to usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_291 (newly downloaded JDK as per the article)

First question is why I have set those JAVA_HOME path to the same one, but java -version in user account is not the JDK that I installed newly.

```
# update-alternatives --list java
/opt/IBM/ace-11.0.0.12/common/jdk/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_291/bin/java
```

I have set to use the newly installed java (/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_291/bin/java) using the sudo command update-alternatives --set java ....

I am able to start sqldeveloper using root. But not able to start sqldeveloper using user account where I have set the SetJavaHome to newly installed Java path.

I tried this https://askubuntu.com/questions/566721/sql-developer-runs-in-terminal-with-sudo-sqldeveloper-but-not-without-sudo where it asked to change the file ownership. But still it doesn't work

I got error when trying to start sqldeveloper

```
 Oracle SQL Developer
 Copyright (c) 2005, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_291/bin/java: relocation error: /usr/lib   /jvm/jdk1.8.0_291/jre/lib/amd64/libnio.so: 
symbol initInetAddressIDs version SUNWprivate_1.1 not defined in file libnet.so with link time reference
```

Second question is how can I approach to solve the error when starting sqldeveloper without using root?

Answer (score 0):

1. The `bashrc` and other profile based scripts like bash_profile etc., that are executed on login are different for different users. Maybe the root users `bashrc` does not have this JAVA_HOME or might have a different version altogether. So make sure the files in the home directory of both these users are have the same version. For more information you can check [What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)
2. The error states that `symbol initInetAddressIDs version SUNWprivate_1.1 not defined in file libnet.so`. This might be an issue of java setup. The .so libraries being fetched might be mixed up. It might work once you fix up 1st issue.

Comment: Can you please re-read my first question as I edited a bit? My root account has the correct java -version which I set using sudo update-alternatives --set java <new JDK installed>, but my user account does not have the correct java -version. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the article that you used to setup @cookick?

Comment: There are 2 links: https://dev.to/ishakantony/how-to-install-oracle-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-20-04-3jpd https://docs.datastax.com/en/jdk-install/doc/jdk-install/installOracleJdkDeb.html @deepakchethan