# Why VS Code on macOS suggests add $PATH to zprofile instead of zshrc?

Tags: macos, zsh

I am studying zsh on macOS and I find when adding software to `$PATH` you are usually supposed to write them in `.zshrc` (zsh). However, Visual Studio Code documentation suggests

> To add VS Code to your path, to do so run the following commands:

```bash
cat << EOF >> ~/.zprofile
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
EOF
```

I find `zprofile` set the environment for login shells while `zshrc` sets the environment for interactive shells. However, I cannot really see differences between two methods on macOS terminal since each terminal tab is a login session on macOS by default.
Is there any reason why Visual Studio Code on macOS suggests add $PATH to `zprofile` instead of `zshrc` and what will be the good practice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash\_profile, and .environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)

Comment: Thank you for a related question. However, it is most about `bash` not `zsh` and also quite old considering the default shell is `zsh` now on macOS. I understand the difference between them but I am confused that since each terminal tab is a login session on macOS by default, is there really difference between setting $PATH in `zprofile` and `zshrc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/415444/6754986) and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119675/218495) as well as the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zsh) (`man zsh` under `STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES`) you might come to the following conclusion:

You are using MacOS, therefore every zsh you open is a login shell, that way you made sure, that `.zprofile` will always be read. So if you append your `$PATH` in your `.zprofile` and and use zsh as a non interactive-shell you will be able to access your appended `$PATH`. This might happen in a script of if other programs try to use a program that you added to your `$PATH`.

Now on the other hand if you added VSCode to your `.zshrc` it will always be available in an interactive shell. Which mean if you use VSCode 'manually' you will always have it at your disposal in zsh. But other programs/scripts might not find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you set environment variables in `.zshrc` or `.zshenv` it can be awkward if you want to use a different value. Say you install a different version of vscode in a different directory. Any new shell will reset the environment variable instead of inheriting it. As environment variables are inherited, there is no need to reset them for every new shell. So `.zprofile` is often a better choice - the variable is set on first login and inherited but can be changed for a shell and its children. Another option is to set them from `.zshenv` but use a condition around them such as `if [[ ! -o privileged && -o rcs && $SHLVL = 1 ]]; then`