# Run terminal command from native terminal rather than stripped down subprocess.run

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have an alias `test` in my .bashrc file. It works if I call it from my standard terminal.

When I run `subprocess.run("test",shell=True)` it gives error: `/bin/sh: 1: test: not found`.

How do I run a shell command **exactly** as if I just opened a terminal and executed it in there, and get the output of the command that it would have printed in my terminal?

Comment: aliases are only active inside an interactive shell - `bash -i` creates one. It's also possible `/bin/sh` points to another shell so you should be explicit and run `bash` e.g. `subprocess.run(["bash", "-ic", "test"])`

Comment: Some related background: [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38175/564341) and [What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/415403/11082165). `.bashrc` is for interactive, non-login shells. If you want to use that alias in non-interactive shells, it probably belongs in a different file.

Comment: If you were using a function instead of an alias, you could export that function into the environment and every copy of the same shell you did the export with (bash if you exported in bash, zsh in zsh, etc) would see it. Aliases are an optional feature -- shells not implementing the interactive extension annex of POSIX don't even support them at all -- and they're worse than functions in almost every way (can't pass arguments through except implicitly in tail position, can't do conditional logic, etc etc etc)

Answer (score 1):

What I would do to call `lso` alias from by `~/.bashrc`:

```
subprocess.run(["bash", "-ic", "lso"])
```

`bash -i` for *interactive*.

Comment: Isn't `source ~/.bashrc` redundant if you're already starting an interactive shell with `-i`?

Comment: Spawning _two_ shell subprocesses seems inefficient. Is there any benefit from creating a `sh` subprocess (`shell=True`) just to start the `bash` subprocess ?

Comment: There's no more 2 shells

Comment: You're still passing `shell=True`. That makes this essentially the same as running `sh -c 'bash -ic lso'` - one shell inside the other.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `shell=True` to spawn a `sh` shell in the background, you can manually spawn a subprocess of your preferred shell:

```py
my_shell = "/usr/bin/bash"  # or fetch from os.environ["SHELL"]

subprocess.run([my_shell, "-ic", "<your shell command(s)>"])
```

The `-i` flag being passed to bash is particularly important. This tells bash to start as an *interactive* shell, which is [required in order for `~/.bashrc` to be read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/415444/11082165).

Note that manually spawning a shell process in this way is more-or-less exactly what passing `shell=True` does in the background. When you start a subprocess as

```py
subprocess.run("blah", shell=True)
```

what "really" happens is essentially the same as writing

```py
subprocess.run(["/bin/sh", "-c" "blah"])
```

Comment: And how do I then actually read the stdout?

Comment: @user56834 That's probably better explained as separate question or in the subprocessing documentation. But TL;DR: what you probably want is passing `capture_output=True` and `text=True` to `subprocess.run`. Then just access the `stdout` attribute to the returned completed process object.